# spike in classes loaded, cpu, and threads in tomcat7 server java

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, garbage-collection, tomcat7

I have been monitoring my tomcat7 server because we have had random crashes. I noticed a spike in loaded classes, cpu usage, and threads all at the same time. When I look at the log4j logs and localhost_access logs, I don't see anything out of the ordinary.

[VisualVM graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OogHg.png)

I also noticed that at the same time all the http-bio-8080-exec theads came online at once.

[VisualVM Threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IayG0.png)

Any Idea what is causing this, and Why are the classes not unloading?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy a new version of an application?  You also have high garbage collection at that time as well as not many classes unloaded.  It is possible your application cannot be unloaded correctly and is building-up on each deploy.

It's worth restarting Tomcat, then watching if the number of classes keeps going up on each deploy.

For futher reading, please see:
[Is there a way to avoid undeployment memory leaks in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565105/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-undeployment-memory-leaks-in-tomcat)