# Internals of how the HashMap put() and get() methods work (basic logic only )

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

When we put a key instance say "key" and a Value instance say "value" in  a `HashMap` class using `put()` method , what does the `HashMap` class do internally . How does it retrieve the value back when we say `hashMap.get(key)` ?

**Edit**: I do not want details here , basically trying to understand the bigger picture and the role of `equals()` and `hashcode()` method in `put()` and `get()` operations.

Comment: did you take a look at the docs / code?

Comment: Here is a link to the source code so that you can read it yourself - http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html  And for a general description of how hash tables work - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @Stephen C see the edited question.

Comment: The bigger picture is obtained by reading up on hashtables.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you mean the wikipedia link that Stephen C has pointed me to ?

Comment: Why not take that as a start. There's plenty of information there and tons more from Google.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Java hashmap work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-java-hashmap-work)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you talk about higher picture it is just like below.Here i refer item as a `key` of `Map`

**While Putting items.**

1. Calculate `hashcode` of key
2. If `basket` with that `hashcode` is present then use the `equals` method on the key search the keys i that basket to determine if the element is to be added or replace.
3. If not there then create new basket (rehashing) and add that element to that.

**Get:**

1. Get the `hashcode` of key
2. Go to that basket
3. Iterate using `equals` on the key will return you that element from that basket.

Comment: don't forget that in step #2 you have to check that basket for the actual item, which is where the .equals() method comes in.  This determines whether you are replacing an existing item or adding a new one.

Comment: @Matt can you update the answer with your point here ? by step#2 , you mean step2 of put or get ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what is done in IBM jdk 1.6 (i believe it is pretty much the same for all vendors)

**EDIT**

Regarding `equals` and `hashcode` you might be interested in seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/579580) post.

**END of EDIT**

```
 /**
 * Maps the specified key to the specified value.
 * 
 * @param key
 *            the key
 * @param value
 *            the value
 * @return the value of any previous mapping with the specified key or null
 *         if there was no mapping
 */
@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putImpl(key, value);
}

V putImpl(K key, V value) {
    Entry<K,V> entry;
    if(key == null) {
        entry = findNullKeyEntry();
        if (entry == null) {
            modCount++;
            if (++elementCount > threshold) {
                rehash();
            }
            entry = createHashedEntry(null, 0, 0);
        }
    } else {
        int hash = key.hashCode();
        int index = hash & (elementData.length - 1);
        entry = findNonNullKeyEntry(key, index, hash);
        if (entry == null) {
            modCount++;
            if (++elementCount > threshold) {
                rehash();
                index = hash & (elementData.length - 1);
            }
            entry = createHashedEntry(key, index, hash);
        }
        if ((cache != null) && (hash >> CACHE_BIT_SIZE == 0)
                && (key instanceof Integer)) {
            cache[hash] = value;
        }
    }

    V result = entry.value;
    entry.value = value;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From `java 8` onwords, there is a performance improvement for `HashMap` objects where there are lots of collisions in the keys by using balanced trees rather than linked lists to store map entries. The principal idea is that once the number of items in a hash bucket grows beyond a certain threshold, that bucket will switch from using a linked list of entries to a balanced tree. In the case of high hash collisions, this will improve worst-case performance from `O(n)` to `O(log n).`

Basically when a bucket becomes too big (currently: `TREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 8`), `HashMap` dynamically replaces it with an ad-hoc implementation of tree map. This way rather than having pessimistic `O(n)` we get much better `O(log n)`.

Bins (elements or nodes) of `TreeNodes` may be traversed and used like any others, but additionally support faster lookup when overpopulated. However, since the vast majority of bins in normal use are not overpopulated, checking for existence of tree bins may be delayed in the course of table methods.

`Tree` bins (i.e., bins whose elements are all `TreeNodes`) are ordered primarily by hashCode, but in the case of ties, if two elements are of the same “`class C implements Comparable<C>`“, type then their `compareTo()` method is used for ordering.

Because `TreeNodes` are about twice the size of regular nodes, we use them only when bins contain enough nodes. And when they become too small (due to removal or resizing) they are converted back to plain bins (currently: `UNTREEIFY_THRESHOLD = 6`). In usages with well-distributed user `hashCodes`, tree bins are rarely used.

Link to [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

[Collection framework enhancements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/collections/changes8.html)