# Confusion with hashmap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I've read all the posts in the topic and I still have confusion on the following: when overriden and collision can happen? From what I'v read I see:

- Whenever two objects are the same in terms of `equals()` method, their hash code must be the same
- Whenever two objects are not the same in terms of `equals()` method, we have no guarantee for theid `hashcode()`, i.e. it might be the same, it might be different
- when we use `HashMap.put(key, value)` HashMap compares objects by their `equal()` method. If the two keys are `equal()` then the new `value` is **overriden**
- If two kays have the same `hashcode` then collision occurs and Java deals with it
- **However** if two keys are equal then the new value is overriden, BUT it also implies that the `hashCode()` must be the same, so collision must happen, which is a contradiction with the previous?

Can someone please clarify these steps for me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559954/internals-of-how-the-hashmap-put-and-get-methods-work-basic-logic-only

Comment: What you wrote was correct. It may be a matter of interpretation: When two objects are equal (and thus have the same hash code) it's not really a "collision that has to be dealt with". The objects are equal, so there is no bucket size that has to be increased or so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your point #3 comes too soon: HashMap compares for equality **only** when the `hashCode` is the same.

`HashMap` checks hash code first to determine the placement of the object in a bucket. The regular `HashMap` keeps only items with identical hash codes (modulo a certain number) in the same bucket, and checks equality only for objects within the same bucket.

Answer (score 4):

Think of a hashmap as a set of pigeon holes. Each pigeon hole can contain more than one object.

The `hashCode()` return is used to select the pigeon hole which either contains or would contain that object.

The `equals()` is used as the criterion to identify a specific object (e.g. for replacement).

The aim of `hashCode()` is to disperse typical objects uniformly across the pigeon holes. Once a particular pigeon hole has been identified as possibly containing an object then all objects in that particular group have to be examined. That operation is expensive since `equals()` needs to be called.