# Contains method replacement in collection

Tags: java, collections, contains

What else i can use instead of contains method of collection to find out the similar entry in the collection.As contains is a very heavy(time consuming) method to use.

Right now i am using contains like this

```
if (EntityTree.setMobileEnablerTxnList.contains(iMobileEnablerTxnList)) {

 }
```

Here setMobileEnablerTxnList is a set.

Comment: *As contains is a very heavy(time consuming) method to use* what makes you think this ? On e.g. a `HashSet` this operation is rather fast.

Comment: @Robin I consider your comment to be the correct answer - ie use a `HashSet`. Consider making it an answer

Comment: @Robing because internally it will check each and every node to find out the right solution.

Comment: @Sunil no it won't, only those in the same bucket (at least if it's a `HashSet`, you haven't said what implementation of `Set` you're using).

Comment: @FrankPavageau yes,Sorry for incomplete information.I am using hashset here and have implemented hashcode as well as equals method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `contains` method is not necessarily *very heavy (time consuming)*. For example if you use a `HashSet` it is rather fast. For a `HashSet` it will calculate the `hashCode` of the object, and only go over the objects in the corresponding 'bucket'. It will certainly not go over all elements (or you would have a very poor implementation of the `hashCode` method).

This can be seen in the source code of the `HashSet#contains` method, which ultimately calls the following code in `HashMap`:

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
    int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
    for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
         e != null;
         e = e.next) {
        Object k;
        if (e.hash == hash &&
            ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return e;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This clearly shows it loops only over a limited set of objects.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-java-hashmap-work) for more information about a `HashMap` (which is used internally by a `HashSet`)

Last piece of advise: if you have performance problems, use a profiler to see where the actual bottleneck is located. I doubt it will be in the `contains` call.

Comment: Thanks,it is really a knowledge gaining answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `List.contains()` iterates through the list checking if the `target.equals(element)`.

If possible, put your list into a `HashSet`, whose `contains()` method always returns very quickly.

Using a `HashSet` would only be of benefit if you can reuse it, because the cost of filling it would tpyically be greater than executing `List.contains()`.

You code code look like this:

Set set = new HashSet(EntityTree.setMobileEnablerTxnList);

if (set.contains(iMobileEnablerTxnList)) {

You would have to make sure that `MobileEnablerTxnList` implements `hashCode()` and `equals()` properly.

Comment: I know it is confusing, but in the question is already stated that ** setMobileEnablerTxnList is a set** (poor naming BTW)

Comment: @Robin I'm beginning to think that the issue is he has `Set<List>`, and that the List hasn't implemented `equals()` or `hashCode()` properly (to reflect its *contents*)

Comment: Even if the collection isn't already a `Set`, the copy in a `Set` probably only makes sense if it's done once and then used for multiple `contains()` calls. Otherwise you're already iterating on the original collection once to fill the `Set`, calling `hashCode()` on the items, then iterating on the items in the same bucket to call `equals()`.

Comment: yes,I m using hashset here,and implemented hascode and equals method also.

Comment: @Robin Thanks a lot robin for highlighting issues,in future will be taking care of them.