# Optimizing Transposing and Comparison of Concurrent List in Java 8

Tags: optimization, java-8, comparator, transpose, nested-lists

I have an application in Java 8 Collecting Data of multiple Threads using `BlockingQueue`.
I need to perform comparison of samples.

But my application is very large, I implemented a mock [application (Github)](https://github.com/joseluisbz/SampleComparator) in Java 8.

I'm generating a chunk of bytes (really is random order).

[image]

The bytes are stored into `ChunkDTO` class.

I implemented a capturer the `ChunkDTO` in a List, code in `Capturer` class.

[image]

Each `ChunkDTO` of List is translated into a List of Samples (`TimePitchValue` exactly) returning a nested List (or List of List of `TimePitchValue`).

[image]

Later the nested List is transposed in order to performs comparisons between `TimePitchValue` with the same time value.

[image]

Due to enormous volume of `TimePitchValue` instances it's consumes huge time in my application.

Here some code ([The complete functional Code is in Github)](https://github.com/joseluisbz/SampleComparator) because is still large for this site).

```
public class Generator {

  final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("SampleComparator");

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long previous = System.nanoTime();
    final int minBufferSize = 2048;
    int sampleRate = 8192;

    int numChannels = 1;
    int numBytesPerSample = 1;
    int samplesChunkPerSecond = sampleRate / minBufferSize;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 10;
    int time = 60 * minutes + seconds;
    int chunksBySecond = samplesChunkPerSecond * numBytesPerSample * numChannels;
    int pitchs = 32;

    boolean signed = false;
    boolean endianness = false;
    AudioFormat audioformat = new AudioFormat(sampleRate, 8 * numBytesPerSample, numChannels, signed, endianness);
    ControlDSP controlDSP = new ControlDSP(audioformat);
    BlockingQueue<ChunkDTO> generatorBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    Capturer capturer = new Capturer(controlDSP, pitchs, pitchs * time * chunksBySecond, generatorBlockingQueue);
    controlDSP.getListFuture().add(controlDSP.getExecutorService().submit(capturer));

    for (int i = 0; i < time * chunksBySecond; i++) {
      for (int p = 0; p < pitchs; p++) {
        ChunkDTO chunkDTO = new ChunkDTO(UtilClass.getArrayByte(minBufferSize), i, p);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("chunkDTO: %s", chunkDTO));
        try {
          generatorBlockingQueue.put(chunkDTO);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage());
        }
      }
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 / chunksBySecond);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
      }
    }
    controlDSP.tryFinishThreads(Thread.currentThread());
    long current = System.nanoTime();
    long interval = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toSeconds(current - previous);
    System.out.println("Seconds Interval: " + interval);
  }
}
```

`Capturer` Class

```
public class Capturer implements Callable<Void> {

  private final ControlDSP controlDSP;
  private final int pitchs;
  private final int totalChunks;
  private final BlockingQueue<ChunkDTO> capturerBlockingQueue;
  private final Counter intCounter;
  private final Map<Long, List<ChunkDTO>> mapIndexListChunkDTO = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());
  private volatile boolean isRunning = false;
  private final String threadName;
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("SampleComparator");

  public Capturer(ControlDSP controlDSP, int pitchs, int totalChunks, BlockingQueue<ChunkDTO> capturerBlockingQueue) {
    this.controlDSP = controlDSP;
    this.pitchs = pitchs;
    this.totalChunks = totalChunks;
    this.capturerBlockingQueue = capturerBlockingQueue;
    this.intCounter = new Counter();

    this.controlDSP.getListFuture().add(this.controlDSP.getExecutorService().submit(() -> {
      while (intCounter.getValue() < totalChunks) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      }
      capturerBlockingQueue.add(new ChunkDTOStopper());
    }));
    this.threadName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }


  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception {
    long quantity = 0;
    isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
      try {
        ChunkDTO chunkDTO = capturerBlockingQueue.take();
        if (chunkDTO instanceof ChunkDTOStopper) {
          break;
        }
        //Find or Create List (according to Index) to add the incoming Chunk
        long index = chunkDTO.getIndex();
        int sizeChunk = chunkDTO.getChunk().length;
        List<ChunkDTO> listChunkDTOWithIndex = getListChunkDTOByIndex(chunkDTO);

        //When the List (according to Index) is completed and processed
        if (listChunkDTOWithIndex.size() == pitchs) {
          mapIndexListChunkDTO.remove(index);
          TransposerComparator transposerComparator = new TransposerComparator(controlDSP, controlDSP.getAudioformat(), index, sizeChunk, listChunkDTOWithIndex);
          controlDSP.getListFuture().add(controlDSP.getExecutorService().submit(transposerComparator));
        }
        quantity++;
        intCounter.setValue(quantity);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("%s\tConsumes:%s\ttotal:%05d", threadName, chunkDTO, quantity));
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
    }
    LOGGER.info(String.format("%s\tReceived:%05d\tQty:%s\tPitchs:%s\tEND\n", threadName, quantity, quantity / pitchs, pitchs));

    return null;
  }

  private List<ChunkDTO> getListChunkDTOByIndex(ChunkDTO chunkDTO) {
    List<ChunkDTO> listChunkDTOWithIndex = mapIndexListChunkDTO.get(chunkDTO.getIndex());
    if (listChunkDTOWithIndex == null) {
      listChunkDTOWithIndex = new ArrayList<>();
      mapIndexListChunkDTO.put(chunkDTO.getIndex(), listChunkDTOWithIndex);
      listChunkDTOWithIndex = mapIndexListChunkDTO.get(chunkDTO.getIndex());
    }
    listChunkDTOWithIndex.add(chunkDTO);
    return listChunkDTOWithIndex;
  }


}
```

`TransposerComparator` class.

The optimization required is in this code, specifically on `transposedNestedList` method.

```
public class TransposerComparator implements Callable<Void> {

  private final ControlDSP controlDSP;
  private final AudioFormat audioformat;
  private final long index;
  private final int sizeChunk;
  private final List<ChunkDTO> listChunkDTOWithIndex;
  private final String threadName;
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("SampleComparator");

  public TransposerComparator(ControlDSP controlDSP, AudioFormat audioformat, long index, int sizeChunk, List<ChunkDTO> listChunkDTOWithIndex) {
    this.controlDSP = controlDSP;
    this.audioformat = audioformat;
    this.index = index;
    this.sizeChunk = sizeChunk;
    this.listChunkDTOWithIndex = listChunkDTOWithIndex;
    this.threadName = this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "_" + String.format("%05d", index);
  }

  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception {
    Thread.currentThread().setName(threadName);
    LOGGER.info(String.format("%s\tINI", threadName));
    try {

      int numBytesPerSample = audioformat.getSampleSizeInBits() / 8;
      int quantitySamples = sizeChunk / numBytesPerSample;
      long baseTime = quantitySamples * index;

      // Convert the List of Chunk Bytes to Nested List of TimePitchValue
      List<List<TimePitchValue>> nestedListTimePitchValue = listChunkDTOWithIndex
          .stream()
          .map(chunkDTO -> {
            return IntStream
                .range(0, quantitySamples)
                .mapToObj(time -> {
                  int value = extractValue(chunkDTO.getChunk(), numBytesPerSample, time);
                  return new TimePitchValue(chunkDTO.getPitch(), baseTime + time, value);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
          }).collect(Collectors.toList());

      List<List<TimePitchValue>> timeNestedListTimePitchValue = transposedNestedList(nestedListTimePitchValue);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
      LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      throw ex;
    }
    return null;
  }

  private static int extractValue(byte[] bytesSamples, int numBytesPerSample, int time) {
    byte[] bytesSingleNumber = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytesSamples, time * numBytesPerSample, (time + 1) * numBytesPerSample);
    int value = numBytesPerSample == 2
        ? (UtilClass.Byte2IntLit(bytesSingleNumber[0], bytesSingleNumber[1]))
        : (UtilClass.byte2intSmpl(bytesSingleNumber[0]));
    return value;
  }

  private static List<List<TimePitchValue>> transposedNestedList(List<List<TimePitchValue>> nestedList) {
    List<List<TimePitchValue>> outNestedList = new ArrayList<>();
    nestedList.forEach(pitchList -> {
      pitchList.forEach(pitchValue -> {
        List<TimePitchValue> listTimePitchValueWithTime = listTimePitchValueWithTime(outNestedList, pitchValue.getTime());
        if (!outNestedList.contains(listTimePitchValueWithTime)) {
          outNestedList.add(listTimePitchValueWithTime);
        }
        listTimePitchValueWithTime.add(pitchValue);
      });
    });
    outNestedList.forEach(pitchList -> {
      pitchList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(TimePitchValue::getValue).reversed());
    });
    return outNestedList;
  }

  private static List<TimePitchValue> listTimePitchValueWithTime(List<List<TimePitchValue>> nestedList, long time) {
    List<TimePitchValue> listTimePitchValueWithTime = nestedList
        .stream()
        .filter(innerList -> innerList.stream()
        .anyMatch(timePitchValue -> timePitchValue.getTime() == time))
        .findAny()
        .orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
    return listTimePitchValueWithTime;
  }

}
```

I was testing:

With 5 Seconds in `Generator` class and the `List<List<TimePitchValue>> timeNestedListTimePitchValue = transposedNestedList(nestedListTimePitchValue);` line in `TransposerComparator` class, Commented 7 Seconds needed, *Uncommented 211 Seconds* needed.

With 10 Seconds in `Generator` class and the `List<List<TimePitchValue>> timeNestedListTimePitchValue = transposedNestedList(nestedListTimePitchValue);` line in `TransposerComparator` class, Commented 12 Seconds needed, *Uncommented 574 Seconds* needed.

*I need to use the application at least 60 minutes.*

With the purpose of reduce the needed (consumed) time, I have two ways:

1. I choose for short is to optimize the methods that I am currently using.
2. That should be successful but longer and is to use `GPGPU`, but I don't know where to start implementing it yet.

**QUESTIONS**

This Question is for the first way: **What changes do you recommend in the code of the `transposedNestedList` method in order to improve speed?**

**Is there better alternative to use this Comparison?**

```
outNestedList.forEach(pitchList -> {
          pitchList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(TimePitchValue::getValue).reversed());
        });
```

Comment: The line `outNestedList.contains` can probably be improved: it does a linear search of an array. Thus its complexity is `O(n^2)`. You could use a hash-set to significantly improve the complexity, and so probably the performance. Moreover, I think there is a *lot* to do before trying to use the GPU: working on better data structures, vectorization, parallelization, caching, reducing copies and allocations! Actually, I do not think porting this code to GPUs will result in faster code than just a good CPU implementation because the computational intensity it quite low (ie. ops/byte).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12191325/811293. https://stackoverflow.com/q/558978/811293