# Simple Grails 2.3+ service for managing a collection taking into account multiple requests

Tags: grails

I would like to create a service which will manage a collection through REST-style controller. I was thinking about what is required to make this Service safe from multiple people hitting it at the same time.

So basically something like this...

```
@Transactional
class NoteService {
    private static users = [:]
    //This won't be so simple it the future
    private static key = 0;
    def get(id) {
        log.debug("We are inside the get")
        return users[id]
    }
    def create(obj){
        log.debug("We are inside the create")
        update(key++, obj)
    }
    def update(id, obj){
        log.debug("We are inside the update")
        users.put(id,obj)
    }
    def delete(id){
        log.debug("We are inside the remove")
        user.remove(id)
    }
}
```

Will this work if I have multiple controller requests hitting it at the same time? My concerns are that there could be problems if two clients are trying to hit it at the same time. Also would there be a better strategy maybe using promises? I am using 2.3+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is broken and not thread-safe.

If you have no mutable state, you are always thread-safe. Of course if you have no state variables at all then it's even better, but it's fine to have state variables for things like dependency-injected Spring beans, or a logger, etc. As long as you don't change those values, then they're effectively immutable (they get set during startup and aren't changed afterwards), and two concurrent callers won't interfere with each other.

But you have exactly the thing that is most problematic for concurrent access - a state variable (in this case it doesn't help or hurt that it's static because by default Grails services are singleton Spring beans, so that map could be a non-static instance variable and have the same problems) that you change in multiple methods.

The easiest thing to do would be to synchronize on the map. You can't just synchronize the methods - that would only work if one method that accessed the map. Using `synchronized` would serialize the calls and guarantee no concurrent access. But you read and write from multiple methods, so serializing calls to each of those doesn't help the interactions between concurrent calls of different methods. Even if you synchronize every method you are still likely to have occasional instances where two methods get called at the same time; being synchronized doesn't help.

So you need a mechanism to synchronize across methods, and you're somewhat lucky here since you only have the one mutable field, so you can synchronize on that (but of course you could always create a dummy 'lock' object and synchronize on that if you had multiple fields being changed). Then all access to all methods (whether they're synchronized or not, and you can now un-synchronize them because that's only slowing things down) is guarded by serializing the calls "through" the map.

This is the easiest, but isn't very performant. If the time spent holding each synchronization lock is short, you probably won't notice much of an issue. Try to make the synchronized blocks as short as possible:

```
def update(id, obj) {
   log.debug("We are inside the update")

   synchronized(users) {
      users.put(id,obj)
   }
}
```

A much better solution would be to use the `java.util.concurrent.*` locking and concurrency classes that were added in Java 5. This will be very performant if implemented correctly, but getting to the point where you understand how to use these APIs will take a while. The best resource is [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601). It was written in 2006  but is still very applicable (it obviously doesn't include updates in newer JDKs, but the APIs available in 1.5 and described in that book are sufficient for many use cases). The book is ~400 pages but the material is difficult (but very well explained), so plan on a multi-month time frame :)

Venkat Subramaniam's [Programming Concurrency on the JVM](https://pragprog.com/book/vspcon/programming-concurrency-on-the-jvm) is another great resource. It's newer (2011) and less in-depth than JCIP, so it covers less but is more approachable. And it covers multiple JVM languages including Groovy. Still a multi-month timeframe, but fewer months.

Comment: This was an awesome explanation, one question so is none of the concurrent stuff wrapped in spring anywhere. Since it was 1.5 seems that someone would have resolved this thing but maybe it is just that complicated :-p. It is going to take me a while to give the check since I have to look through all that material but for now kudos on the explanation!

Comment: Not that I know of. They do have abstractions for thread pools, executors, etc., and http://gpars.codehaus.org/ is a much more significant collection of async functionality (and it's Groovy based), but both are more for creating your own multithreaded calls, not protecting from them. I think the solutions aren't very generalizable, so there's not much a framework could help with.

Comment: The tricky part is that you can create an object containing only thread safe components that will be non-thread safe. That's why its hard (if not impossible) to manage thread safety outside of your implementation

Comment: This looks interesting, am I wrong in thinking this could possibly work? http://gpars.codehaus.org/Agent

Comment: Perhaps, but it made me realize that I was off track - I mentioned the `j.u.c.` package but was thinking about locks, synchronizers, etc. But all you need to use is a `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`. Read the Javadoc to see how it's both threadsafe (when used correctly) and has low locking and concurrency overhead. You have to use the map correctly though, e.g. using new methods like `putIfAbsent`. There's a good discussion of this here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14947723/160313

Comment: I would say that last comment is the real answer after looking at some of the documentation @BurtBeckwith I think the other answer would be to use a HashTable. My cubemate said I failed his interview because I didn't know the difference between HashMap and HashTable :-p

Comment: Yep, sorry for the intermediate confusion. And it's still a great idea to read that book :) HashTable wouldn't work. Every method is synchronized, but that doesn't guard against 2 threads calling 2 different synchronized methods concurrently. `ConcurrentHashMap` does what you want - no method is synchronized but rather concurrent access is carefully protected by the internal implementation. Nowadays there's almost no reason to us HashTable or Vector, which does the same for ArrayList but isn't truly threadsafe. Use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` for a genuinely threadsafe List.

Answer (score 0):

What about this to be a little more "Groovy"? I went ahead and used the Gpars you recommended I am just not sure I used them correctly :-p. I tried it and it seems to be working ok.

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import grails.converters.JSON
import groovyx.gpars.agent.Agent;

@Transactional
class NoteService {
    private static key = 0
    private final  noteState = new Agent<Map<String, String>>([:])
    def get(id) {
        return noteState.val[id]
    }
    def create(obj){
        noteState << { it[(key++).toString()] = obj }
    }
    def update(id, obj){
        noteState << { it[id] = obj }
    }
    def delete(id){
        noteState << { it.remove(id) }
    }
}
```