# ConcurrentHashMap operations ordering guaranties

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, concurrenthashmap

Lets imagine situation:

**thread_1** put value to map (it continues from **time_1** to **time_4**)

**thread_2** want to read value from *same segment*(request was send at **time_2**)

**thread_3** want to put value to *same segment* at **time_3**.

Is there guaranties about ordering of these operations?

**P.S.**
time_1 happens before time_2
time_2 happens before time_3
time_3 happens before time_4
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _ordering_ and _happens before_? What does the javadoc of the class say and what don't you understand about it?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis who will win thread_2 or thread_3 ?

Comment: What do you mean _win_? Win what?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis which operation will be executed first?

Comment: Don't these sentences in the Javadoc explain it? "Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset."

Comment: You said at `time_2` and `time_3`, I don't know how you control that, but there's your answer.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I have added picture to the topic

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352707/what-happens-when-two-threads-trying-to-put-the-same-key-value-in-concurrent-has

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, Why do you think that it is duplicate ?

Comment: Because that's the answer I would've given.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis, I didn't find it

Comment: You're showing a `get` before a `put`. Obviously, the `get` won't retrieve a value that hasn't been `put` yet. Maybe I don't understand your confusion. _Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations_

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis oops, Do you want to say that read and write can ocсure in parallel?