# What kind of the Map interface I should use?

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to make the following class thread-safe:

```
//Shared among all threads
public class SharedCache {

    private Map<Object, Future<Collection<Integer>>> chachedFutures;
    {
        chachedFutures = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); //not sure about that
    }

    public Future<Collection<Integer>> ensureFuture(Object value,
                                                     FutureFactory<Collection<Integer>> ff){
        if(chachedFutures.containsKey(value))
            return chachedFutures.get(value);
        Future<Collection<Integer>> ftr = ff.create();
        chachedFutures.put(value, ftr);
        return ftr;
    }

    public Future<Collection<Integer>> remove(Object value){
        return chachedFutures.remove(value);
    }

}
```

After reading the [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08223/index.html) about the [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) class it's still difficult for me to make a right decision.

Firstly, I tended to make the methods `ensureFuture` and `remove` just `synchronized`. And it would work, but from the performance standpoint it was not very good because of mutually-exclusing.

I don't know the exact (even approximately) amount of threads having access to the `Cache` simultaneously and the size of the Cache. Taking into account that

> resizing this or any other kind of hash table is a relatively slow
>   operation

I didn't specify the initial size of the map. Also the [concurrencyLevel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#ConcurrentHashMap%28int,%20float,%20int%29) parameter. Is it justified to use `ConcurrentHashMap` here or synchronized methods would be enough?

Comment: It may also depend on whether you want your data to be consistent. The `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe per se, but will not guarantee the consistency of your data. The right idiom for both consistency and thread-safety (at the cost of performance) would be synchronizing on a `Collections.synchronizedMap`.

Comment: @Mena but it's just a decorator, therefore it garuntees that the only one thread can have acces to the map at a time.

Comment: That's if you synchronize on the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have following methods:

```
     public Future<Collection<Integer>> ensureFuture(Object value,
                                                     FutureFactory<Collection<Integer>> ff){
        if(chachedFutures.containsKey(value))
            return chachedFutures.get(value);
        Future<Collection<Integer>> ftr = ff.create();
        chachedFutures.put(value, ftr);
        return ftr;
    }

    public Future<Collection<Integer>> remove(Object value){
        return chachedFutures.remove(value);
    }
```

There are some points to be noticed:

1. Suppose method `ensureFuture` is not synchronized in that case it is possible that one thread invokes `containsKey` which returns `true` but before next line is executed another thread may remove the entry respective to that key. This can lead to race condition as it is `check-then-act` scenario. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947723/is-concurrenthashmap-totally-safe) as well.
2. Also you are using `chachedFutures.put(value, ftr)` but IMO you should use `chachedFutures.putIfAbsent(value, ftr)` . For this method `if the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to null) associates it with the given value and returns null, else returns the current value`. Using this you can also avoid contains check.

> Is it justified to use ConcurrentHashMap here or synchronized methods
>   would be enough?

It depends as CHM needs more memory compared to HashMap due to lot of bookkeeping activities etc. Another alternative is to use `Collections.synchronizedMap` which will provide synchronization on a regular `HashMap`.

Comment: Good advice to use `putIfAbsence`, indeed. So, using the method will make the class thread-safe, right? Also it will have a better performance than the synchronized version has.

Comment: If you use method `putIfAbsence` it will save you from the `check-then-act` problem.

Comment: Got it. Let me ask you one more question. I'm not sure about safety if one thread's trying to remove a value and another one ensuring the same value.

Comment: In that case (when other thread ensures the same value) it may not be a problem but prevention is better than cure :). Moreover race condition should always be cured.

Comment: You mean, to use locking preventing it explicitly?

Comment: Nope. I mean avoid race condition as that is a problem. Locking is one way of solving this problem. We have other ways too. Also optimistic locking can also provide better results.