# About dual key concurrent hashmap in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap, multikey

I need dual key concurrent hashmap.

My first try is just using **java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap**. Like this

```java
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.put("key1" + "|" +"key2", "value");
String vaule = map.get("key1" + "|" +"key2");
```

but I think this is ugly.

My Second try is using Object as Key. Like this

```java
@Data
public class DualKey {
    private final String key1;
    private final String key2;
}
```

```java
map.put(new DualKey("key1", "key2"), "value");
String vaule = map.get(new DualKey("key1", "key2"));
```

Last try is create DualkeyConcurrentHashMap. I just need put, get, containsKey.

```java
public class DualkeyConcurrentHashMap<K1, K2, V>  {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<K1, ConcurrentHashMap<K2, V>> map 
                                                    = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public V put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<K2, V> subMap 
                    = map.computeIfAbsent(key1, k -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
        return subMap.put(key2, value);
    }

    public V get(K1 key1, K2 key2) {
        ConcurrentHashMap<K2, V> subMap = map.get(key1);
        return null == subMap ? null : subMap.get(key2);
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K1 key1, K2 key2) {
        return null != get(key1, key2);
    }
}
```

Is it better and perfectly thread safe?
(I can't decide all method need **synchronized**.)

Is there another recommended way?

Comment: As you already have (probably) working code for all solutions, perform a benchmark - you will see if there are any differences and you will answer your question. Love to see results.

Comment: I don't like value object approach, cuz you have to create object just to get value from map

Comment: The first option doesn't actually work for all keys: it would get the same value for `"a", "b|c"` and for `"a|b", "c"`.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(key1, key2)` provides you with an a working key. You have to care not to modify that object, but it’s concise and can easily replaced with Java 9‘s `List.of(key1, key2)` which gives you an immutable key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[All options are thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947723/is-concurrenthashmap-totally-safe), which is guaranteed by `ConcurrentHashMap`. Important [fact to note is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval
>   operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for
>   locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access. This class
>   is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its
>   thread safety but not on its synchronization details.

The natural way to implement a dual key map would be to provide an object, so I would go with the second one, only that I would make `DualKey` generic.

The first one couples implementation and design (`string1 "|" + string1` key format) and does not allow you to change types used as keys easily.

The third one uses much more instances of `ConcurrentHashMap` than needed.