# How does HashMap work with two objects with same hash code

Tags: java

If `object1` and `object2` are two different types of objects but implement the same interface `I`, and we assume `object1` and `object2` have same hash code.

There is a `HashMap<I, String>`.

So we can call `put(object1, "some string")` and `put(object2, "some string")` by that hash map.

My understanding is:

1. For `put()` function, the position of the object in hash map depends
   on the hash code of the key object. After the `object1` put into the
   map first, then we try to put `object2`. It will find the position has
   been occupied by `object1` already. So the `object2` will be put into
   `object1`'s next position.
2. For `get()` function, if we call `get(object2)`, it will find `object1`
   first, and find `object1 != object2`, then it will continue to compare
   the next element of object1 until find the same object with `object2`

Just want to know if I am correct?
Or any supplement information within this mechanism.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Or read the source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a HashMap work in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

This would be considered to be a hash collision.  Most likely the hash implementation will find the same bucket and then walk down each entry until equals() returns true for the key.  All reasonable hash implementations have to account for the possibility of collisions, but these degrade the hashing performance.

Answer (score 1):

Refer these links, 1.[how HashMap works in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html) and 2.[how HashMap works in Java](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/09/how-hashmap-works-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right with your understanding. Refer Effective Java for even better understanding.