# Where can I find a documentation Vector and Hashtable in Java?

Tags: java, vector, collections, hashtable

I know this question can be a little stupid but I just want to clear the doubt.
When going through Java tutorial for Collection ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html ), I didn't find any relevant information about both Vector and Hashtable. Both belong to Collection framework as Vector is implementation of List and Hashtable is implementation of Map. If it is so then why it is not in Sun tutorial? Where can I find Sun tutorial for Collection which contain good doc about both Vector and Hashtable and in depth knowledge about elements storing in List, Set and Map?

Comment: Vector is an implementation of List, not Set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Vector` and `Hashtable` are old, legacy collection classes. Don't use them.

Instead of `Vector` use `ArrayList`; instead of `Hashtable` use `HashMap`.

When Java 1.2 was released (very long ago), new collection classes were added to Java (the Collections Framework). Sun did not remove the old classes such as `Vector` and `Hashtable` because they wanted the new Java version to be backwards compatible. And now we still have those old classes.

One difference to be aware of is that `Vector` and `Hashtable` are synchronized, while `ArrayList` and `HashMap` are not. Most of the time you don't need synchronization; if you do, then you must take care to synchronize your `ArrayList`, and if you need a map, use `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of plain `HashMap`.

Comment: Thanks Jesper for the answer. But can I get old Java tutorial for Collection that include Vector and Hashtable like the recent one on Collection by Sun. Secondly any tutorial which say about in depth knowledge about elements storing in List, Set and Map (Sun doc will be preferred)?

Comment: You can lookup those classes in the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/). They work almost the same as other list and map classes, so why do you need a special tutorial for these old classes? The tutorial you already found explains exactly how to use lists, sets and maps.

Comment: I read about collection and it say hashset stores its elements in a hash table and hashtable stores in bucket. I am just eager to know what is bucket. how element is added in that and when remove it is remove from rear end or front end. How hashcode helps a hashtable. Does hashcode is also stored in bucket. if so how etc etc. I hope you understand what I want to tell.

Comment: Those are questions about how `HashMap` or `Hashtable` works internally - not things you would find in a tutorial on how to use these classes. See [my answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6493946/135589) for an idea of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

In general, `Vector` and `Hashtable` could be considered deprecated.

If you look at the online javadoc for [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) and [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) you'll see that they were the original implementation of `ArrayList` and `HashMap`, until the Collections framework came along, at which point they were retrofitted to implement interfaces from the Collections framework; this way, old classes that depended on those classes being there would not break. The only difference between them and their more common brethren is that they are synchronized.

In the vast majority of cases, synchronization isn't called for, so programmers will avoid the synchronization overhead and opt for regular `ArrayLists` and `HashMaps`. If a synchronized collection is desired there's always `Collections.synchronized____()` (or `ConcurrentHashMap`) that would work just fine too.

You probably don't need a tutorial for `Vector` and `Hashtable` because their behavior is already so similar to classes you're likely to be familiar with, and because they aren't used much any more. As for more info on `List`, `Set`, and `Map`, the online javadoc is a [good](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) [place](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to [start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 0):

here are useful links for you
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2010/10/difference-between-hashmap-and.html

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/difference-vector-vs-arraylist-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the JavaDoc of [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html):

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

it is kind of a legacy implementation of the `List` interface. The whole collection framework has been implemented to be by default not thread-safe. If you need thread safety, you may wrap any non tread-safe implementation by using the proper `Collections.synchronizedXXX()` methods, where `XXX` is `List` or `Map` or `Set` for example. The same applies for HashTable, which is by default synchronized as well. You should use `HashMap` instead and `Collections.synchonizedMap()` instead.