# Searching Map by value field

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have a Map implementation where I have to create a query whereby using value name field I need to return Key to that object.

One way is to use an iterator through the KeySet and check every Value, but it's not very efficient.

Time is an important factor.

Are there any interesting solutions/ libraries doing this?

Comment: If you need quick lookup of key by value, and your Map is large, you should consider creating a second Map where the original value is the key and the original key is the value.

Comment: @Eran - assuming that both the keys and the values are unique.

Comment: If the keys are not unique your second map may look like `Map<V, List<K>>`

Comment: @Forin Please consider my solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use BiMap from the Guava framework:
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap

Answer (score 0):

yes.
using the Bidi Map :- [Bidi Map](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html)

[Download jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscollectionsjar.htm)

[How to use.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/userguide.html)

Example:-

```
BidiMap bidiMap = new DualHashBidiMap( );
bidiMap.put( "il", "Illinois" );
bidiMap.put( "az", "Arizona" );
bidiMap.put( "va", "Virginia" );
// Retrieve the key with a value via the inverse map
String vaAbbreviation = bidiMap.inverseBidiMap( ).get( "Virginia" );

// Retrieve the value from the key
String illinoisName = bidiMap.get( "il" );
```

Using the same approach you just need to implement the `hascode()` and `equals()` contract of a Map.
Solution :-

1. we know that `HashCode` is used to Store in `Bucket`. Assume `hashcode` as row number in `2-D matrix` and each Row has the linked List of `entry[key,value]`.
2. implement the `hashcode()` such that for each `entry[key,value]` you will get different `bucket no(row no).
3. Implement `equals()` method to check the equality in each bucket's entry[key,value].
4. Complexity :- if you assign each `entry[key, value]` to the different bucket then `SEARCHING` and `ADDING` complexity will be **o(1)**.
5. please refer the below documents for better understanding of solution:-[doc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302169/what-happens-if-we-override-only-hashcode-in-a-class-and-use-it-in-a-set/43839835#43839835) [doc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911369/hashmap-java-8-implementation)