# Ordering for key value pairs

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have the following two classes:

```
class KeyClass {
    private prop1;
    private prop2;

    hashcode() {
    //implemented properly
    }

    equals() {
    //implemented properly
    }
}

class ValueClass {
    private prop1;
    private prop2;

    hashcode() {
    //implemented properly
    }

    equals() {
    //implemented properly
    }
}
```

I am trying to find out the max pair from a map where objects of these classes are key and value pairs respectively. I also have an `com.google.common.collect.Ordering<ValueClass>` which uses multiple comparators. I can easily find out the max of values using this ordering, but what I am interested into is the key of the max value.

I can write a certain implementation wherein I can keep track of my key w.r.t the value in a loop and use the ordering to compare values (similar to the conventional way of finding a max value) but I want to know if we already have such case handled by `Guava` or any other library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say guava or any other library and that's straightforward with Java 8 streams. If your `Ordering<ValueClass>` instance is called `ordering`:

```
Entry<KeyClass, ValueClass> maxEntry = map.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue, ordering))
        .orElse(null);
```

Add `.map(Entry::getKey)` before `orElse` to get just the key.

The above is possible since guava's `Ordering` implements `java.util.Comparator` so you can pass it as argument to [comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you do the following:

Change your `com.google.common.collect.Ordering<ValueClass>` to `com.google.common.collect.Ordering<Map.Entry<KeyClass, ValueClass>>` and modify the multiple `Comparator<ValueClass>` that are used to use `Map.Entry#getValue` instead.

Thus, the maximum `ValueClass` will be equivalent to the maximum `Map.Entry<KeyClass, ValueClass>`.

> I can easily find out the max of values using this ordering, but what I am interested into is the key of the max value.

Now, you can simply use `Map.Entry#getKey` to grab the key of the maximum value/entry.

Answer (score 1):

yes.
using the Bidi Map :- [Bidi Map](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html)

[Download jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonscollectionsjar.htm)

[How to use.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/userguide.html)

Example:-

```
BidiMap bidiMap = new DualHashBidiMap( );
bidiMap.put( "il", "Illinois" );
bidiMap.put( "az", "Arizona" );
bidiMap.put( "va", "Virginia" );
// Retrieve the key with a value via the inverse map
String vaAbbreviation = bidiMap.inverseBidiMap( ).get( "Virginia" );

// Retrieve the value from the key
String illinoisName = bidiMap.get( "il" );
```

Using the same approach you just need to implement the `hascode()` and `equals()` contract of a Map.
Solution :-

1. we know that `HashCode` is used to Store in `Bucket`. Assume `hashcode` as row number in `2-D matrix` and each Row has the linked List of `entry[key,value]`.
2. implement the `hashcode()` such that for each `entry[key,value]` you will get different `bucket no(row no).
3. Implement `equals()` method to check the equality in each bucket's entry[key,value].
4. Complexity :- if you assign each `entry[key, value]` to the different bucket then `SEARCHING` and `ADDING` complexity will be **o(1)**.
5. please refer the below documents for better understanding of solution:-[doc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302169/what-happens-if-we-override-only-hashcode-in-a-class-and-use-it-in-a-set/43839835#43839835) [doc2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911369/hashmap-java-8-implementation)