# Using Guava multisets or Collections.frequency()?

Tags: java, collections, guava, multiset

I was using [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) to have easy access to the freq of elements, but I realize there is [`Collections#frequency(Collection<?>, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency-java.util.Collection-java.lang.Object-) that does the same for any collection. What is the point of using `Multiset` then? Is performance an issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guava documentation for [Multiset#count()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#count(java.lang.Object)])
has to say:

> Note that for an Object.equals(java.lang.Object)-based multiset, this gives the same result as Collections.frequency(java.util.Collection, java.lang.Object) (which would presumably perform more poorly).

So, yes, I suspect that performance is the issue here.

I think `Multiset#count` is more efficient because `Collections#frequency` iterates through the entire collection. For an object o whose frequency you're checking, it goes through all elements e in the collection and checks `(o == null ? e == null : o.equals(e))`.

For Multiset (which is an interface), the exact implementation of `count` depends on the class. If it is a `HashMultiset`, for example, then it is backed by a `HashMap`. For details about how that is more efficient than iterating through the whole collection, take a look at this answer: [How does a Java HashMap handle different objects with the same hash code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java).

The [Guava code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultiset.java) is as follows

```
public int count(@Nullable Object element) {
    Count frequency = Maps.safeGet(backingMap, element);
    return (frequency == null) ? 0 : frequency.get();
}
```

Similarly, for a `TreeMultiset`, which maintains the ordering of its elements and is backed by an AVL tree, `count` can be obtained in O(log(n)) steps instead of O(n), where n is the size of the collection. The [Guava code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.java) is as follows:

```
public int count(@Nullable Object element) {
    try {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          E e = (E) element;
          AvlNode<E> root = rootReference.get();
          if (!range.contains(e) || root == null) {
              return 0;
          }
      return root.count(comparator(), e);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
          return 0;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
          return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm missing one simple point in your answer: If a `Multiset` contains one element a million times, `Collections.frequency` will iterate it a million times while `Multiset` simply finds the element (your Big-O-notation applies) and says "one million".

Comment: For Multiset, `n` typically refers to the number of _distinct_ elements, whereas for e.g. a `List` it's going to refer to the total number of elements, distinct or not.