# How to aggregate the occurrence with enum

Tags: java, object, arraylist, enums, find-occurrences

I have a `ScenarioGenerator` class to generate the `Scenario`. And in the `Audit` class, I set the function to decide how many scenarios to be generated and wanted to print out the occurrence of each enum type (`Gender` in this case).

I've referred to [Counting an Occurrence in an Array (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618205/counting-an-occurrence-in-an-array-java/29618366)

I used the frequency method to count the occurrence, but when there are many scenarios generated, I don't know how to aggregate the data. What I've tried was:

1. Generate the scenarios and add each scenario in the ArrayList
2. For each scenario, I get the passenger ArrayList, and save their attributes in different collections.
3. For each collection, print out its value and the count.

I can simply do like this:

```
int maleCount = Collections.frequency(genderCollection, Gender.MALE);
System.out.println(Gender.MALE.toString().toLowerCase() + ":" +maleCount);
```

However, if I have more enums and attributes, this method becomes lengthy and inefficient. Is there any way to deal with this?

Here is part of my `Audit` class:

```
public class Audit {

private Scenario scenario = new Scenario();
private ScenarioGenerator scenarioGenerator = new ScenarioGenerator();
private Person person = new Person();

private String auditType;
private int nubmerOfSimulation;

public enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE, UNKNOWN;
}

public Audit() {

}

// create a specific number of random scenarios
// the concept similar to gamePlayed and gameWon in the last project
public void run(int runs) {
    this.nubmerOfSimulation = runs;
    ArrayList<Scenario> scenarios = new ArrayList<Scenario>();//create a arrayList to store each scenario

    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        Scenario singleScenario = scenarioGenerator.generate();
        scenarios.add(singleScenario); // save each scenario into a scenario arrayList
    }
    survialCalculator(scenarios);        
}

public int survialCalculator(ArrayList<Scenario> scenarios) {
    //person attribute arrayList
    ArrayList<Gender> genderCollection = new ArrayList<Gender>();

    for (Scenario scenario : scenarios) { // for each scenario, getting its passengers and pedestrians
        ArrayList<Character> passengers =  scenario.getPassengers();
        for (Character passenger : passengers) {
            if (passenger instanceof Person) {
                Gender gender = ((Person) passenger).getGender();
                //System.out.println(gender);
                genderCollection.add(gender);    
        }
    }

    //try to print out the elements in the collection and its frequency, but failed
    for(Gender genderElement : genderCollection) {
        int genderCount = Collections.frequency(genderCollection, genderElement);
        System.out.println(genderElement.toString().toLowerCase()+ ":" + genderCount);
    }

    return 1;

}
```

Here is part of my `ScenarioGenerator`:

```
public class ScenarioGenerator {


private Person person = new Person();
private Random random = new Random();   

private int passengerCountMinimum;
private int passengerCountMaximum;

private int pedestrianCountMininum;
private int pedestrianCountMaximum;

private ArrayList<Character> passengers = new ArrayList<Character>();
private ArrayList<Character> pedestrians = new ArrayList<Character>();

public Person getRandomPerson() {
    //need age, gender, bodyType, profession, pregnancy
    int age = random.nextInt(100);
    int profession = random.nextInt(person.getProfessionEnumLength());
    int gender = random.nextInt(person.getGenderEnumLength());
    int bodyType = random.nextInt(person.getBodyTypeEnumLength());
    int pregnancy = random.nextInt(2);

    Person people = new Person(age, 
                               Profession.values()[profession], 
                               Gender.values()[gender],
                               BodyType.values()[bodyType], 
                               pregnancy == 1 ? true : false);
    return people;
}

public Animal getRandomAnimal() {
    //species, isPet
    int age = random.nextInt(100);
    int gender = random.nextInt(person.getGenderEnumLength());
    int bodyType = random.nextInt(person.getBodyTypeEnumLength());
    boolean isPet = random.nextBoolean();


    String [] species = {"cat", "dog"};
    int idx = random.nextInt(species.length);
    String pickSpecies = species[idx];


    Animal creature = new Animal(age, Gender.values()[gender], BodyType.values()[bodyType] , pickSpecies); 
    creature.setIsPet(isPet);

    return creature;       
}
//getters and setter of min and max numbers of passengers and pedestrians
public Scenario generate() {

    //random number of passengers and pedestrians with random characteristics
    //randomly red light or green light
    //random condition "You" in the car
    //abide by the minimum and maximum counts from above setters

    //get random numbers abide by the setters
    int numberOfPassengers = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(getPassengerCountMin(), getPassengerCountMax()+1);
    int numberOfPedestrains =ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(getPedestrianCountMin(), getPedestrianCountMax()+1);

    boolean legalCrossing = random.nextBoolean();

    //generate the number from the total numbers of passenger and pedestrians
    int numberOfPersonPassenger = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, numberOfPassengers+1);
    int numberOfAnimalPassenger = numberOfPassengers - numberOfPersonPassenger;

    int numberOfPersonPedestrian = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, numberOfPedestrains+1);
    int numberOfAnimalPedestrian = numberOfPedestrains - numberOfPersonPedestrian;

    //generate the number of person passengers
    for (int i = numberOfPersonPassenger; i > 0; i--) {
        Person person = getRandomPerson();
        passengers.add(person);
    }

    //remaining of the number of passengers should be animals
    //no matter it is pet of not
    for (int i = numberOfAnimalPassenger; i > 0; i--) {
        Animal animal = getRandomAnimal();
        passengers.add(animal);
    }

    for (int i = numberOfPersonPedestrian; i > 0; i--) {
        Person person = getRandomPerson();
        pedestrians.add(person);
    }

    for (int i =numberOfAnimalPedestrian; i > 0; i--) {
        Animal animal = getRandomAnimal();
        pedestrians.add(animal);
    }
    Scenario scenario = new Scenario(passengers, pedestrians, legalCrossing);

 return scenario;

}
```

Here is part of my `Scenario` class:

```
public class Scenario {
private Random random;

private ArrayList<Character> passenagers = new ArrayList<Character>();
private ArrayList<Character> pedestrians = new ArrayList<Character>();

private boolean legalCrossing;


public Scenario() {

}

public Scenario(ArrayList<Character> passengers, ArrayList<Character> pedestrians, boolean isLegalCrossing) {
    this.passenagers = passengers;
    this.pedestrians = pedestrians;
    this.legalCrossing = isLegalCrossing;
}
//getters and setters
```

The main class is to call the method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ethicalEngine.generate();

}
public void generate() { 
    Audit audit = new Audit();
    audit.run(5); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` stream operation on `List<Gender>` to get map of all gender type with count.

```
Map<Gender, Long> counted = genderCollection.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

And print this way

```
for (Map.Entry<Gender, Long> item : counted.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(item.getKey().toString()+ ":" + item.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using the [Guava Multiset](https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html). As Stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374200/using-guava-multisets-or-collections-frequency) this data structure is more efficent when you have more attributes to count as the access to the number lies [most of the time in O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055243/is-a-java-hashmap-really-o1).

Comment: Thank you, sir. What if I can't use the library? Is there any way?

Comment: You could try to use a `HashMap` instead. Check if it already contains the enum and then increase the count. To check wether a key is already part of the map is averagely in O(1). Same goes for accessing the map. You can also try to implement your own MultiSet based of [the code](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.java) form the Guava project.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try.