# How HashMap retrieves different values if Key's hashcode is same but equals method return false

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I'm not able to understand on working pattern of HashMap. Kindly help to understand it.

Say we have two objects **Obj1** and **Obj2** having same Hashcode as **1212**. Now when we run "==" and equals it returns false.

Now i use **ValueObj1** and **Valueobj2** as value in a HashMap with Keys **Obj1** and **Obj2** respectively. **I believe both the values will be save in same bucket making as List**.

My question how HashMap picks  **Valueobj2  for Obj2 and  ValueObj1 for Obj1**. Say there are n.. such objects and values.
How this key--> value association works internally even though hashcode is same but values are different.

***Assuming both condition equals is not overridden and overridden***.

Comment: I believe this is not answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `HashMap`/`HashSet` implements per bucket a list of keys (on the case of a `Map` together with the values). If multiple key's share the same `hashCode` value, they are placed in this list.

So the search method first extracts the `hashCode` of the queried key and then iterates over the corresponding list until an `equals` method succeeds. In case of a `HashSet` it means the `key` is found, in case of a `HashMap`, it returns the other side of the tuple: the value.

The memory of a `HashMap` thus works like:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|   00   |   01   |   10   |   11   |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |        |        |        |
 k00/v00     _     k06/v06     _
    |                 |
 k08/v08           k14/v14
    |                 |
 k04/v04              _
    |
    _
```

What you see is on top the four buckets. Each bucket has a list (the items underneath), that stores tuples of keys (`k`) and values (`v`). Since there are here only four buckets, the hash algorithm uses a modulo 4 operation, so a key `k06` with value `v06` would be placed in bucket `06 mod 4 = 02` thus `10`. In case a second key `k14` is added with `14 mod 4 = 02` thus `10`, it is simply added to the list.

Since the values are stored with it as well, one can perform a fast lookup operation. The **key is thus stored together with the value**.

You noticed, that iterating over the (linked) list is an expensive operation. But the point of a `HashMap` is that one hopes, that the number of *hash-collisions* to use the correct term (number of keys sharing the same bucket) is very low. In general one might expect two or three elements per bucket. The **performance boost is thus achieved by selecting the correct bucket in constant time**, searching the bucket requires however linear time (or in case there is a complete ordering on the key's, one might implement a (balanced) binary tree to search in logarithmic time). Worst-case however, a `HashMap` can achieve, the same performance as an `ArrayList`/`LinkedList` of entries, but given the *hash*-function has been designed decently, the odds are very low.

Comment: Hi, so you mean key is also stored with value in the bucket?

Comment: Hi, you mean if we say map.get(key5) it will pick fifth value from the bucket....then why to maintain a linkedlist??? although the complexity is o(5) "for fifth value"

Comment: @PawanKumar: no since one generally maintains a large number of buckets, picking the correct bucket will in general result in an extreme performance boost. But indeed, if the hash-function is chosen poorly and all items reside in the same bucket, a `HashMap` behaves as linear search.

Comment: Very nicely explained answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

[You can always look at the code.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java)

```
 public V get(Object key) {
     if (key == null)
         return getForNullKey();
     int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
          e != null;
          e = e.next) {
         Object k;
         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
             return e.value;
     }
     return null;
 }
```

1. So it first gets the hash for the given key.
2. Using that hash it locates the table (referred to in other answers as a bucket).
3. For every entry in the bucket it tests if the key `equals` the table entries key and if so it has found the correct item.

Partitioning keys by hashes in to buckets reduces the size of the linear search using `equals` comparisons. So you can see how harmful it is to return a fixed value for hashcode. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation) for tips on good hashcode calculation.

Comment: So same question you mean key is also stored with value in the bucket  so the key can be compared with key....

Comment: @PawanKumar Yes, they are kept together in the `Entry<K,V>` objects in the bucket.

Comment: @PawanKumar That is why you must have a good hash code calculation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113511/hash-code-implementation

Answer (score 3):

`HashMap` works by dividing its content into buckets based on the hash value of the key. Each bucket in turn contains a list of entries, an entry consisting of the key and the value.

Let's say we want to look up `x` in the map. We calculate `x.hashCode()` and pick the appropriate bucket. We then iterate through the bucket's list and pick the entry `e` where `e.key` equals `x`. We then return `e.value`.

Pseudocode:

```
class Map {
    class Entry {
        Object key, value;
    }

    List<List<Entry>> buckets;

    Object get(Object key) {
        List<Entry> bucket = buckets.get(key.hashCode() % buckets.size());
        for (Entry entry : bucket) {
            if (Object.equals(key, entry.key) return entry.value;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer: Using % to calculate a bucket index is an oversimplification and wouldn't work as-is; it's just there to convey the general idea)

Answer (score 0):

`hashcode()` method is called and hash code is calculated. This `hashcode` is used to find index of array for storing Entry object.

`indexFor(hash,table.length)`  is used to calculate exact index in table array for storing the Entry object.

two key objects having same `hashcode`(which is known as collision)

In hash map, bucket used simple linked list to store objects .

if two keys have same hashcode, then store the key-value pair in the same bucket as that of the existing key.

**How do you retrieve value object when two keys with same hashcode are stored in hashmap?** 
Using hashcode wo go to the right bucket and using equals we find the right element in the bucket and then return it.

**HashMap get() function**

If key is not null then , it will call hashfunction on the key object.

```
int hash = hash(hashValue)
```

`hashvalue` is used to find the bucket location at which the Entry object is stored . Entry object stores in the bucket like this `(hash,key,value,bucketindex)` .

detail read [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-internal) and [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two objects with `==` is not a good idea since it checks if two objects are actually links to the same objects in memory.

There is a good [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) on Wikipedia about hashtables. `Hashmap`'s in java has inside an array of "buckets".

When you put a new pair `<key, value>` (or in your case `<obj1, valueObj1>`) the bucket number is calculated depending on `obj1.hashcode()`. This pair is added into the selected bucket which is a `LinkedList` inside to store actual pairs `<key, value>`.

When you try to search for an `valueObj1` with key-object `obj1` hashmap calculates a bucket number where that pair is located and iterates over all that `LinkedList`'s elements comparing keys with `equals()`. If instantly `equals()` returns `true`, it means that the element we are looking for is found.