# Duplicate values in a hashSet

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, hashset

I am trying to count the number of combinations of 1, 5, 10 and 25 that sum to n. Given that I don't want any repetitions (like 1+5 = 6 and 5+1 = 6). I am using a `hashSet`. I implemented a class named `ResultSet` that saves the number of 1, 5, 10, and 25 in a solution and I overrode the `equals` method. However, for some reason, my solution `hashSet` keeps returning duplicate values. Why?

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Solution {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 6;
    int combinationsSolution = new Combine(N).getSolution();
    System.out.println("N= " + N + " Number of solutions= " + combinationsSolution);

  }
}

class Combine {

  private int solution;

  private int n;

  private HashSet<ResultSet> cacheUnordered = new HashSet<ResultSet>();

  public Combine(int N) {
    this.n = N;
    this.solution = solve(n);
  }

  public int getSolution() {
    return solution;
  }

  public int solve(int N) {
    solve(N, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (ResultSet r:cacheUnordered){
      System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
    return cacheUnordered.size();
  }

  public void solve(int N, int substracted1, int substracted5, int substracted10, int substracted25) {
    if (N == 0) {
      cacheUnordered.add(new ResultSet(substracted1, substracted5, substracted10, substracted25));
    } else if (N > 0) {
      solve(N - 1, substracted1 + 1, substracted5, substracted10, substracted25);
      solve(N - 5, substracted1, substracted5 + 1, substracted10, substracted25);
      solve(N - 10, substracted1, substracted5, substracted10 + 1, substracted25);
      solve(N - 25, substracted1, substracted5, substracted10, substracted25 + 1);
    }
  }
}

class ResultSet {
  private int numberOf1;

  private int numberOf5;

  private int numberOf10;

  private int numberOf25;

  public ResultSet(int num1, int num5, int num10, int num25) {
    numberOf1 = num1;
    numberOf5 = num5;
    numberOf10 = num10;
    numberOf25 = num25;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    String result;
    result = numberOf1 + " " + numberOf5 + " " + numberOf10 + " " + numberOf25;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object r2) {
    if (r2 == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!(r2 instanceof ResultSet)) {
      return false;
    }
    ResultSet rr = (ResultSet) r2;
    if (rr.numberOf1 == this.numberOf1 && rr.numberOf5 == this.numberOf5
            && rr.numberOf10 == this.numberOf10 && rr.numberOf25 == this.numberOf25) {
      System.out.println("Comparing " + this.toString() + " to " + rr.toString());
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public int getNum1() {
    return numberOf1;
  }

  public int getNum5() {
    return numberOf5;
  }

  public int getNum10() {
    return numberOf10;
  }

  public int getNum25() {
    return numberOf25;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your `ResultSet` class, you defined an `equals()` method but not a `hashCode()` method.  You need both methods for `HashSet` to work correctly.  Please see this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java).  (It talks about HashMap, but it also applies to HashSet.)

Answer (score 3):

As [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) Clearly Specified

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method
>   whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general
>   contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must
>   have equal hash codes.

and you have not followed it , that is why you get duplicates ,

[Please Read How HashCode and Equals Work](http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/09/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-methods-in-java/) it will help you out to understand the above statement better