# Hashtable returning null but object key is present

Tags: java, hashtable

EDIT:  FML!  MY implementation of hashcode had a lowercase c.  -.-

I've been trying to learn TDD and have been following the 'By Example' book by Kent Beck; it's very good!

However, I can't seem progress because a value is returning null when I access a hashtable.  I've run a debug session and the object with the value is clearly there yet the result is null.

The code to build and access is:

```
public void addRate(String from, String to, int rate){
    this.rates.put(new Pair(from, to), new Integer(rate));
}
```

from and to are "GBP" and "USD".  Also verified by debug.

Test case calling the above:

```
@Test
public void testreduceMoneyDifferentCurrency(){
    Bank bank = new Bank();
    bank.addRate("GBP", "USD", 2);
    Money result = bank.reduce(Money.gbpound(2), "USD");
    assertEquals(Money.dollar(1), result);
}
```

The reduce method in bank calls the method rate:

```
public Money reduce(Bank bank, String to){
    int rate = bank.rate(this.currency, to);
    return new Money(this.amount / rate, to);
}
```

Which is where the issue is:

```
    public int rate(String from, String to){
    if (from.equals(to)) return 1;
    Integer rate = (Integer) this.rates.get(new Pair(from, to));
    return rate.intValue();
}
```

The first line copes with USD -> USD conversions etc.

The Pair object is 2 strings built to be used as a key.

I've not used has tables a great deal but I can't see what the issue is, I know for certain that the values are in the hashtable but 'rate' is always returning a null value.

I can't see the wood for the trees. :)  Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `Pair` method. 
When you do this:

`this.rates.get(new Pair(from, to));`

you are creating a new instance of `Pair`, which is not the same as the one you've put into the map in the `addRate` method.

If you want the code to work correctly, you either have to use the same instance of `Pair` class or correctly implement `equals` and `hashCode` method on `Pair` class.

Here's a bit deeper insight into the inner working on HashMap and what you have to do to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493946/2266098

Comment: He also needs to make `Pair` immutable.

Comment: thank you, my equals method is: public boolean equals(Object object){
        Pair pair  = (Pair)object;
        return this.from.equals(pair.from) && this.to.equals(pair.to);
    }
But, I'll now look at how I create and pass in the key, I have a direction so thank you for that! :D

Comment: With your equals method it should work, but you also need to provide the `hashCode` method, which will return same result for same values. To confirm that it is working, you could just make the hashCode() method which returns 0 all the time. Performance-wise this will reduce the HashMap to LinkedList, but you will fullfill the contract, which merely says that two objects must have the same hashCode if they are equals.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj, ah, my hashcode does return 0. It's quite simply :  public int hashcode(){
        return 0;
    }

Comment: my hashcode method used a lowercase c.  FML :) thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Java keeps the reference of objects. So when you are trying to do this
`this.rates.get(new Pair(from, to));`
you are basically creating a new instance of `Pair` which does not exists as a key in your `HashMap`.

Comment: Why adding a duplicate answer?

Comment: when i was writing, the answer did not exist.