# Can a StringBuffer be used as a key in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

Can a StringBuffer as a key in a HashMap? 
If so, what is the difference between using a String and a StringBuffer as the key?

Comment: What language or library are you referring to? You ought to tag your question with it.

Comment: @jB         language is java

Answer (score 5):

> Can a StringBuffer as a key in a HashMap?

No, since [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) overrides neither `equals` nor `hashCode`, so it is not suitable as a `HashMap` key (recall that `HashMap` relies on those two methods to tell if a given key is present in the map).

Beyond that, `StringBuffer`s are mutable, and you typically want `Map` keys to be immutable. From [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects `equals` comparisons while the object is a key in the map. A special case of this prohibition is that it is not permissible for a map to contain itself as a key. While it is permissible for a map to contain itself as a value, extreme caution is advised: the `equals` and `hashCode` methods are no longer well defined on such a map.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot, unless you want to distinguish between separate buffers instead of their contents. The `StringBuffer` class does not implement `equals` or `hashCode` which means it inherits these methods from `Object`. The `Object` implementation of these methods only distinguishes between object instances, not their contents.

In other words, if you would have two `StringBuffer` instances with the same contents, they would not be considered equal. Even weirder, if you would reinsert the same buffer with a different value, it *would* be considered equal to the previous one.

---

In general you should take care using mutable values as keys. Mutations will not alter the position in the `Map`, as the `Map` instance will not be notified of the change. In this case, since `equals` is not implemented anyway, this issue will not come up.

Answer (score 0):

All classes in java are intended to be used as hash keys, because all of them inherit the supermethod `hashCode`. Altough there are some cases in which, though it might compile well, would be quite weird, like Connection or Streams... or StringBuffer. This is why:

The main difference between `String` and `StringBuffer` is that a String is *immutable* by design, and it contains a proper implementation of `hashCode`. `StringBuffers`, instead, may change, and because of this, this class does not have a proper implementation of `hashCode`: It does not override the default implementation inherited from `Object`. Now you can see the consequences: A StringBuffer cannot contain a hash of high quality, nor coherent with its contents, damaging then the result of the hashing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any object can be used as a key in a `HashMap`, although that may not be a good idea.

> Class HashMap
>
> ```
> Type Parameters:
>     K - the type of keys maintained by this map
>     V - the type of mapped values
> ```

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code):

> When you put a key-value pair into the map, the hashmap will look at
>   the hash code of the key, and store the pair in the bucket of which
>   the identifier is the hash code of the key. (...) Looking at the above
>   mechanism, you can also see what requirements are necessary on the
>   `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods of keys (...)

Do notice, however, that [`StringBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) **does not override** the required methods so your "key" will be the object's memory address. From [the `hashcode()` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of
>   the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not
>   required by the JavaTM programming language.)

Meaning it's use as a key will be very different than `String`'s:

```
Map<String, String> hashA = new HashMap<>();
a.put('a', 'a');
System.out.println(hashA.get('a')); //prints 'a'

Map<StringBuffer, String> hashB = new HashMap<>();
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer('a');
hashB.put(buffer, 'a');
System.out.println(hashB.get(new StringBuffer('a'))); //prints null
System.out.println(hashB.get(buffer)); //prints 'a'
```