# invalid hash entry after 100000 + entries

Tags: java, hashmap

I've implemented a HashMap with Linear Probing for hash collisions.

```
import java.util.Optional;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public abstract class HashMap<T, R> {

    private static final int MIN_CAPACITY = 2;
    private Entry<T, R>[] table;
    private int internalSize, size;
    private float fillRatio;

    public HashMap() {
        this(MIN_CAPACITY);
    }

    public HashMap(int initialCapacity) {
        this(initialCapacity, .75f);
    }

    public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float fillRatio) {
        this.table = new Entry[Math.max(MIN_CAPACITY, initialCapacity)];
        this.fillRatio = fillRatio;
    }

    public Optional<R> put(T key, R value) {
        int index = getIndex(key);
        Entry<T, R> current = table[index];
        table[index] = new Entry<>(key, value);

        if(value == null && current != null && current.getValue() != null) {
            size--;
        } else if(value != null && (current == null || current.getValue() == null)){
            size++;
        }

        if(current == null && ++internalSize >= (table.length * fillRatio)) {
            resizeTable();
        }

        if(current != null) {
            return Optional.ofNullable(current.getValue());
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public Optional<R> get(T key) {
        int index = getIndex(key);
        Entry<T, R> entry = table[index];
        if(entry != null)
            return Optional.ofNullable(entry.getValue());
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public boolean has(T key) {
        return get(key).isPresent();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    protected void resizeTable() {
        internalSize = size = 0;
        Entry<T, R>[] tmp = table;
        table = new Entry[(int) ((table.length /fillRatio)* 2)];
        for(Entry<T, R> entry : tmp){
            if(entry != null) {
                put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    private int getIndex(T key) {
        int hash = key.hashCode();
        int index = (((hash % table.length) + table.length) % table.length);
        while(table[index] != null && table[index].getKey().hashCode() != hash) {
            if(++index == table.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    public static final class Entry <T, R> {
        private final T key;
        private final R value;

        public Entry(T key, R value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public T getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public R getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

}
```

it seems to work exactly as expected except for every 100,000 entries or so will return the wrong value for a hash. I can reproduce it fairly reliably with this test

```
        java.util.HashMap<UUID, UUID> javaMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();
        HashMap<UUID, UUID> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
            UUID key = UUID.randomUUID(), value = UUID.randomUUID();
            javaMap.put(key, value);
            map.put(key, value);
        }

        for (java.util.HashMap.Entry<UUID, UUID> entry : javaMap.entrySet()) {
            Optional<UUID> value = map.get(entry.getKey());
            assertTrue(value.isPresent());
            assertEquals(value.get(), entry.getValue());
        }
```

I'm not seeing what my problem is and I'm not thinking of a good way to debug such a rare occurrence. Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong or how to debug this without spending forever on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How does a Java HashMap handle different objects with the same hash code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code?rq=1) answered my question. My HashMap implementation does not handle different objects with the same hash code. It only works correctly if hashcodes are unique to equal objects.

Comment: I was really surprised that uuids give the same hashCode on so short distance. Btw `while(table[index] != null && table[index].getKey().hashCode() != hash && table[index].getKey.equals(key))` should solve this problem. I think you've already done it.

Comment: yea, it really is surprising how frequently uuids have identical hashcodes.