# HashMap doesn't work with user defined key class

Tags: java, hashmap, processing

I am using Processing language (derived from Java PApplet) version 3.01

Here is my code...

```
  Pig a = new Pig(1);
  Pig b = new Pig(1);
  HashMap<Pig, String> m = new HashMap<Pig, String>();
  m.put(a,"foo");
  String c = m.get(b);
  println(c);  

class Pig {
  int a;
  Pig(int x) { a=x;}
  boolean equals(Pig b) { return b.a==a;}
  int hashCode() { return a;}
}
```

As you can see I am using Pig for key, I defined the equals and hashCode. I expect output "foo", however, I get output null.

Any idea what is going on here?  Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You did not add `b` to the HashMap. Therefore you cannot retrieve it, even if there is another object in the HashMap, which's `equals` method returns true.

Comment: You didn't override equals.

Comment: @hotzst : that's precisely what he's trying to do, get "foo" wihtout adding b because a and b should be considered equals.

Comment: HashMap uses the hashCode only as part of its hashing algorithm. Thereby even if an equal element is in the HashMap with the same `hashCode` it will not land in the same bucket. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that, you didn't override Object methods at all / correctly :

```
class Pig {
    int a;

    Pig(int x) {
      a = x;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object b) {
      if(b == null) return false;
      if(!(b instanceof Pig)) return false;
      if(b == this) return true;
      return ((Pig) b).a == a;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return a;
    }
  }
```

Comment: wow override equals must handle many cases. I didn't think of them all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't override `equals(Object)`, but you did implement an unrelated `equals(Pig)` method. `HashMap` uses the former, your method isn't even called.