# Why do we need to check hashcode twice?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashcode

This is the code of HashMap.java (docjar). Hash for key is calculated on line 431. This helps to fetch the index i on line 432. This all the entries at that index should have the same hash. Why is the check for hash equality made again on line 440 ? `(if (e.hash == hash )`

```
private void putForCreate(K key, V value) {
  430           int hash = (key == null) ? 0 : hash(key.hashCode());
  431           int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
  432   
  433           /**
  434            * Look for preexisting entry for key.  This will never happen for
  435            * clone or deserialize.  It will only happen for construction if the
  436            * input Map is a sorted map whose ordering is inconsistent w/ equals.
  437            */
  438           for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
  439               Object k;
  440               if (e.hash == hash &&
  441                   ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))) {
  442                   e.value = value;
  443                   return;
  444               }
  445           }
  446   
  447           createEntry(hash, key, value, i);
  448       }
```

Comment: Which version of Java? There is no `putForCreate` in OpenJDK 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same bucket may contain entries whose keys have different hash codes (since the bucket index `i` is determined by applying modulus `table.length` on the computed hash, so different hash codes may be mapped to the same bucket), so the comparison in line 440 saves you the need to call `equals` for the two keys that don't have the same hash code, which would normally be more expensive than comparing two `int`s.

Comment: can a bucket hold 2 different hashcodes ??

Comment: @Rehman yes, it can. Suppose you HashMap has 16 buckets. Then both hashCodes 3 and 19 will be mapped to the same bucket - 3.

Comment: Are you sure ? I dont think so .Then how a hashcode can determine a bucket ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code
"The hash code of the key is 235 -> the pair is stored in bucket number 235".