# Why HashSet can contain multiple objects with same properties if hashCode not overridden?

Tags: java, hashcode

I encountered this question during [OCPJP](https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=458&get_params=p_track_id:OCPJSE7).

Given the code:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Person)) return false;
        Person p = (Person)o;
        return p.name.equals(this.name);
    }
}
```

And the following statements (only one of which is true):

- A. Compilation fails because the hashCode method is not overridden
- B. A HashSet could contain multiple Person objects with the same name.
- C. All Person objects will have the same hash code because the hashCode method is not overridden
- D. If a HashSet contains more than one Person object with name="Fred" then removing another Person, also with name="Fred", will remove them all.

The answer is (B), but I don't understand why. Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does a Java HashMap handle different objects with the same hash code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code)

Comment: Do you know why classes overriding `equals` should also override `hashCode`?

Comment: Don't post a screen shot of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Yes I know that, but the problem is the given answer for this question. How does this hashset could contain multiple Person objects with the same name ??

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule: always make sure that if `obj1.equals(obj2)`, then `obj1.hashCode() == obj2.hashCode()`

In your case, since `hashCode` isn't being overridden, it's using the default one defined in `Object`, which does not take into account any properties of the object - you'll generally find that `new Object().hashCode() != new Object().hashCode()`.

With this case, if you have two `Person` objects with the same name, they will most likely end up with different hashCode values, allowing them to coexist in the set: your `HashSet` can contain multiple `Person` objects with the same name, which is answer (B).

This is why it's important to override both `hashCode` and `equals` - if your objects are equal, but don't generate the same hashCode, they won't behave properly when using them in hash-based collections.  [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) has a bit more details on what happens in different cases.

Comment: But I have heard that actually equals method is responsible for identifying unique items in a set. Which it does in the above equals method according to my knowledge. Is it ?? 
Then how two similar objects can co-exist in the set ??

Comment: Ok, took a little time to understand. When hashCode() direct the object to a certain bucket then it checks for all the element in it for equality. if no equal item found it is added to it. I hope my understand is correct !!

Comment: Yup, you've got it :)