# I'm using .hashCode() to create hashes. Is there a library to perform double hashing in Java to resolve collisions?

Tags: java, hashmap, collision, hashcode, hash-collision

As a homework problem, I'm trying to create an implementation of a hashmap using an array. I'm using .hashCode() to create the hash, and I need to find a way to resolve collisions.

I thought of using double hashing, but I can't find a way to do that in Java. I've also tried searching on SO, but most of the questions are discussing how collision resolution is handled etc, rather than how to implement a solution. Would anyone be able to point me to any simple alternatives if there isn't a library to perform double hashing?

Comment: Sounds like the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You don't provide enough information to help understand why is it that you have a lot of collisions: maybe the size of the array is too small? Maybe you are using a load-factor which is too small? maybe your objects override hashCode in a bad way? and etc...

Comment: It's not so much that I'm having a lot of collisions, part of the assignment is to create a way to handle collisions if it happens. I'm using an array that is 1.3 times the size of the input array.

Comment: The JDK uses a binary tree when the keys of a `HashMap` collide if the keys implement `Comparable`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556142/chained-hash-tables-vs-open-addressed-hash-tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double hashing is probably what you'll want to do in production-code, but for a class exercise this is probably an overkill.

What you should do instead, is implement a linked-list attached to each [bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959941/what-exactly-is-bucket-in-hashmap) of the hashmap, and when you have a "collision" (meaning, more than one object is mapped to the same key in the array) you just add another link to the list with the new object. A good illustration can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37960112/1057429).

A nice explanation along with visual graphs that demonstrate this solution can be found here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-hashmap-java/

You might also find the following SO question + answers relevant:
[What exactly is bucket in hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959941/what-exactly-is-bucket-in-hashmap)