# Why the HashSet add the Objects not in the order as in the code?

Tags: java, hashset

This is what i tried.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SetDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashSet<String> s1=new HashSet<String>();
        s1.add("Java");
        s1.add("C++");
        s1.add("C");
        s1.add("dotNet");
        s1.add("JavaScript");
        s1.add("Script");
        s1.add("Python");
        s1.add("JavaScript");
    }
}
```

Output
[Java, Script, C++, dotNet, C, JavaScript, Python]

Edit:[Just read this , i think it might be answer to what i was asking](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-hashmap-java/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Set retain order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752753/java-set-retain-order)

Comment: Because it uses hashing, which by definition assigns a random position to elements added. The point of this is to get O(1) time complexity.

Comment: @user13784117 this is not right. Sets have no order by nature. All members of the sets are equal in matter. [wikked it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type))...

Comment: (1) This is Java programming, not mathematics, See TreeSet. It's a Set with order. (2) But for mathematics - consider the set of natural numbers. Do you contend there is no ordering?

Comment: Who said mathematics? I see you don't follow random links so I will quote: **In computer science, a set is an abstract data type that can store unique values, without any particular order. It is a computer implementation of the mathematical concept of a finite set. Unlike most other collection types, rather than retrieving a specific element from a set, one typically tests a value for membership in a set.** The most intuitive implementation would use hashing and then what you said will be true.

Comment: ok, thanks got it. Actually i wanted to see the how that set would have been implemented in java.

Comment: @PranavMittal then maybe you would like to read [about buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959941/what-exactly-is-bucket-in-hashmap)

Comment: @dbl - ok, I'll rephrase - it's Java programming, not theoretical computer science. Java has something it calls a Set which is ordered.  But in any case, the OP is talking specifically about a HashSet, to *only* which my original comment applied.

Comment: @user13784117 [TreeSet-Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle%E2%80%93ellipse_problem#:~:text=The%20circle%E2%80%93ellipse%20problem%20in,subtype%20polymorphism%20in%20object%20modelling.&text=The%20existence%20of%20the%20circle,to%20criticize%20object%2Doriented%20programming.)?

Answer (score 5):

From the [relevant JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html):

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table
> (actually a HashMap instance). **It makes no guarantees as to the**
> **iteration order of the set**; in particular, it does not guarantee that
> the order will remain constant over time. This class permits the null
> element.

Basically, a HashSet:

- stores unique elements and permits nulls
- is backed by a HashMap
- doesn't maintain insertion order
- is not thread-safe

Answer (score 2):

You need you to use `LinkedHashSet<>()` for the same.

```
import java.util.*;
public class SetDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashSet<String> s1=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        s1.add("Java");
        s1.add("C++");
        s1.add("C");
        s1.add("dotNet");
        s1.add("JavaScript");
        s1.add("Script");
        s1.add("Python");
        s1.add("JavaScript");
    }
}
```

You can also use the `SortedSet` if you want natural order.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good answer. Might also want to update to include `SortedSet` if OP wanted to use natural order and not insertion order.

Comment: It sounds to me more like the OP would like to use a list instead...

Comment: @Jason completely agree with you if we need natural order then we can use `SortedSet`

Comment: However, one ought to ask **why** the OP thinks maintaining insertion order is desirable for his use.