# Difference between Bucket and Node in HashMap

Tags: java, nodes, bucket

If two objects have same `hashCode`, they would go into same **bucket**, which is same index in `hashTable`. Thing that surprised me is that I read some people say **bucket=node**.But is it?

After JVM checks they are not equal, it would store both of those two objects into `bucket` using `linkedList` implementation. Is that where are they in `nodes` now or what are they called here now?

I am sorry for not being precise. Can someone correct me as I am bad at terminology here. And I saw few sources not being precise about that.

Bottom line: What are nodes and what are buckets in this simple 'story'? Thanks :)

Comment: Does [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37959941/what-exactly-is-bucket-in-hashmap) answer yours?

Comment: A node is one single key-value pair. A bucket is a collection of nodes. In HashMap the collection is a linked list at first but if the number of nodes gets big enough it's changed into a binary search tree