# HashMap<K,V> only by hashCode()

Tags: java, dictionary

I've just realised `HashMap<K,V>` checks `k.hashCode() = key.hashCode()` and `k == key`.

So, it's regardless whether `k is "equivalent" to key`, `k must be == to key`.

Is it possible to change this behaviour in order to use only `hashCode()` equivalence?

Comment: This question is not at all the same as the nominated dupe.  That question speaks to why `equals()` should be consistent with `hashCode()`, but this one is about how to implement / use a `Map` such that keys having the same hash code are considered equivalent for the map's purposes.  They're related, but closely so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, it's regardless whether `k` is "equivalent" to `key`, `k` must be `==` to `key`.

No, that is incorrect, as @KevinWallis already observed.  `HashMap` uses `hashCode()` to identify the correct hash bucket, and *`equals()`*, not `==`, to compare keys that fall into the same bucket.  Types that have a meaningful sense in which distinct instances are equivalent are supposed to describe that via their `equals()` methods, and standard library types such as `String` and `Integer` in fact do so.  When the keys are of such a type, you do not have to use the same object to retrieve a value from a `HashMap` that you did to store it.

On the other hand, types that do not have a meaningful sense in which distinct instances are equivalent should not, and generally do not, override `equals()` (or `hashCode()`).  The implementation inherited from `Object` yields the same result as the `==` operator, which makes it possible and sensible to use such objects as `HashMap` keys or to store them in `HashSet`s, at least under some circumstances.

> Is it possible to change this behaviour in order to use only hashCode() equivalence?

It is not possible to change the behavior of `HashMap` in this regard.  If you were able to do so then the resulting map would not correctly fulfill the `Map` contract.  You can, however, implement your own map-like class that behaves as you describe, or you can create a wrapper class to use as a substitute key type.

Example key class:

```
class HashEquivalenceKey<T> {
    private final T object;

    public HashEquivalenceKey(T object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return ((o == null) ? 0 : object.hashCode());
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ((o != null) && (this.hashCode() == o.hashCode()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No `hashCode` does a grouping for you (put the elements into buckets) and in the bucket the `equals` is used for comparison.

Check the following link: [How does a Java HashMap handle different objects with the same hash code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code)

Comment: Ok. I got it. It's necesary to implement `equals()` beside to `hashCode()` as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to change this behaviour in order to use only hashCode() equivalence?

Yes, you can override `equals` to return true when the two compared objects have the same `hashCode()`. Whether or not it would make sense is another matter.

```
public class SomeKeyClass
{
    boolean equals (Object other)
    {
        if (!(other instanceof SomeKeyClass)) // you can skip this condition too, but it
                                              // makes sense to require the two objects to
                                              // be of the same class in order for them to
                                              // be equal
            return false;
        return hashCode () == other.hashCode ();
    }
}
```