# Why HashMap is overriding existing string key value

Tags: java, hashmap

```
String abc = "abc";
String abc2 = new String("abc");
System.out.println(abc == abc2); //false
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put(abc, 2);
System.out.println("map.get(abc)" + map.get("abc")); //2
map.put(abc2, 1234);
System.out.println("map.get(abc)" + map.get("abc")); //1234
```

If `abc` and `abc2` are not equal then why `Hashmap` is overriding values?

Comment: `abc` and `abc2` are equal! You are not checking for equallity on line 3 but if they are the same object. `abc.equals(abc2)` is how you check if they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` is a structure that will store (`key/value`)(called `Entry`) elements and where `keys` will be `unique`

Since `abc.equals(abc2)` is `true`, `abc2` will replace `abc`

---

To check equality you need to use `.equals()` and not `==` which is for reference

`abc` and `abc2` are not the same `object` (`==` is `false`) and they represent the SAME string (`.equals()` is `true`, and so only one can be in the `Map`)

```
String abc = "abc";
String abc2 = new String("abc");
System.out.println(abc.equals(abc2)); //line 3 :  true
map.put(abc, 2);      
map.put(abc2, 1234);                  //because of line 3 it will override precedent input (line 4)
System.out.println(map.toString());   //[abc=1234]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **`abc.equals(abc2)`** is always `true` for those values.

While **`abc == abc2`** is not necessarily `true` for their references.

---

And that being said you shall be able to understand

```
map.put(abc, 2);
map.put(abc2, 1234); // overrides the previous value with the same key
```

Answer (score -1):

String generates the hash based on the value, the key will be the same for both objects so both objects are pointing to the same key (hash) & abc.equals(abc2 ) is true So both objects are pointing to the same entry.

String abc = "abc";
    String abc2 = new String("abc");

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    if (h == 0 && value.length > 0) {
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            h = 31 * h + val[i];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Thats not even the correct answer. What matters is that both Strings are equal! HashMap is perfectly capable of handling multiple unequal objects with the same hashcode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code

Comment: I forgot to add abc.equals(abc2 ) I think now it is ok