# Value not inserted inside an HashMap from put()

Tags: java, hashmap

Consider the following code snippet :

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] arg)       {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    map.put("ONE", new BigInteger("1"));
    map.put("TWO", new BigInteger("2"));
    map.put("THREE", new BigInteger("3"));
    map.put("FOUR", new BigInteger("4"));
    map.put("FIVE", new BigInteger("5"));
    map.put("SIX", new BigInteger("6"));

    System.out.println("Hello !");
}
```

The result is:

- Map's `size` is 6.
- Map's `table` contains the following content:

  ```
  [FIVE=5,
   SIX=6,
   ONE=1,
   TWO=2,
   THREE=3]
  ```

`FOUR` disappeared. As a comment stated before, it would be wise to calculate the `hashCode` of my entries, modulo the size of the map. It gives the following result:

```
ONE : 0
TWO : 0
THREE : 1
FOUR : 2
FIVE : 3
SIX : 4
```

As we can see, the `hashCode` does not indicate anything considering the collision of `FOUR` with any value. This also works with `ConcurrentHashMap` and `LinkedHashMap`, so I guess it is a `HashMap` problem.

Can someone explain to me what is actually going on ? I'm quite lost on this one.

---

I'm working with:

- Eclipse Neon
- JDK 8

Comment: I have executed your code and the result for me is: `{ONE=1, TWO=2, THREE=3, FOUR=4, SIX=6, FIVE=5}`

Comment: Is this the whole code?

Comment: Makes no sense as collisions don't prevent element adding. An element is replaced only as the  key of the added element is equals to its key. Note that your code doesn't output the map.

Comment: Yes it is, and I would love to have your result @canillas, I swear. It would have saved me some effort.

Comment: I mean that maybe the error is not in this piece of code... It's the whole code?

Comment: @canillas this code is sufficient and completely fine. Read the answers for the reason behind this behavior. Yassine, you might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code?noredirect=1) for more details about HashMap's internals.

Comment: Your code is fine. Eran and Seelenvirtuose's answer showed me why I was wrong. `HashMap` are working with buckets, and `FOUR` is stored in the same bucket as `ONE`. The difference between actual size and table put me in trouble there, thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HashMap`'s internal table (which is in fact a simple array) does not store the values but a list-like structure whose elements now store several values.

A hash map calculates the hash value of the keys being put into it. Distinct keys that yet have the same hash code go into the same list (indexed in the table array).

Have a look into the source code of `HashMap.Node`:

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next;
    ...
}
```

Each node inside that list stores the key, the value, the hash code, and a pointer to the next node of that list.

Your example code builds up the following table:

```
 [2] FIVE = 5    =>   null
 [3] SIX = 6     =>   null
 [7] ONE = 1     =>   FOUR = 4   =>   null
[13] TWO = 2     =>   null
[15] THREE = 3   =>   null
```

By the way ... Printing the whole map yields the following:

```
{FIVE=5, SIX=6, ONE=1, FOUR=4, TWO=2, THREE=3}
```

Comment: Great explaination, I did not know about storing values in a list, that gave me a rough time. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

"FOUR" did not disappear. You saw for yourself that the map's size is 6, and if you'll print the map, you'll see all 6 entries.

If you look more carefully in your debugger, you'll see that keys "ONE" and "FOUR" are mapped to the same bucket (index 7). This can happen even if they don't have the same hash code (since `HashMap` performs some additional computation on the `hashCode()` of the key, and then performs `% table.length` on the result to obtain the index of the bucket).

[image]

In your example, the hash value computed for "ONE" is 78407, and for "FOUR" it's 2163975. Since the default initial number of buckets is 16, the bucket is computed by 78407 % 16 == 2163975 % 16 == 7, so both keys are stored in the same bucket.