# Android Set doesnt delete checked then unchecked value in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, checkbox, hashset

I have an array list that contains all the checked items and a hashset to prevent duplications. But now I have a problem that the array list still stores the previously checked items even though i have unchecked it.

I have looked for solutions like Hashset and using (!isChecked) but those wont delete the previously stored value.

```
       viewHolder.checkBox.setTag(dataModel.getChkBool());


    viewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        citiesSelection.add("\n" + dataModel.getCity());
                    }

            //prevent duplicates
             hashSet.addAll(citiesSelection);
             citiesSelection.clear();
             citiesSelection.addAll(hashSet);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Checked Total: " + citiesSelection, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
```

Screenshots:

[Checked boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyi4B.jpg)

[Unchecked, but the arraylist still contains the previously checked ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpUrA.jpg)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use an `ArrayList` and a `HashSet`? If you need to preserver the order of the elements and prevent duplicates, why not just use [LinkedHashSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/LinkedHashSet)?

Comment: @LuCio If I dont use the HashSet, each time i check and uncheck a checkbox it will just add on to the list, showing duplicate value.

Comment: As far as I can see using a `LinkedHashMap` would reduce the complexity and maybe resolve your issue too since there is no need to determine the proper state using two collections.

Comment: I have implemented LinkedHashSet and its less complex now, but it doesnt remove the previously checked value.

Comment: If `citiesSelection` is a `LinkedHashMap<String>` thus it contains the names of the cities then `onClick` should look like that: `if (viewHolder.checkBox.isChecked()) {             citiesSelection.add(dataModel.getCity());
        } else {
            citiesSelection.remove(dataModel.getCity());
        } Toast.make ...`

Comment: I have tried that too, it should work in theory but somehow it doesnt.

Comment: Did you note that I omiited `"\n"` in my code snippet.?

Comment: Owh sorry I didnt notice the \n removed. It is fine now, Thanks a lot! Wonder how a \n affects this.

Comment: `"\nLondon".hashCode() != "London".hasCode()` and `"\nLondon".equals("London") == false`. Further reading: [How does a HashMap work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493605/how-does-a-java-hashmap-handle-different-objects-with-the-same-hash-code)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, removing the \n and using citiesSelection.remove(dataModel.getCity()); fixes it thanks to LuCio

Comment: The reason is: [see my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887739/android-set-doesnt-delete-checked-then-unchecked-value-in-arraylist?noredirect=1#comment92691516_52887739)