# Java HashSet remove item by using its hash code

Tags: java, hash, set, hashset, hashcode

I have a class with its own hashCode() method. I am adding this class to a HashSet. How can I remove an item by its hashCode, without knowing the object itself?

For example, if I have the following code

```
HashSet<Data> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(new Data(10, 5));
...
class Data {
    public int importantVal;
    public int notImportantVal;
    //... constructor ...
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return importantVal;
    }
}
```

and I knew the `importantVal` of a Data object, but not the object itself. How would I remove it? `set.remove(10)` does not work.

Best solution I can think of is to also override `equals()` to return if `importantVal` is the same, and then do `set.remove(new Data(10, anyPlaceholderValue))`

I am looking for a O(1) solution. I obviously know how to loop through the HashSet and check each element, but that is too slow.

Comment: You do realise that hash codes may not be unique, right? There could be multiple unequal objects in a set, that all have the same hash code. Do you want to remove all of them in that case?

Comment: "Best solution I can think of is to also override `equals()` to return if `importantVal` is the same". So `equals` _isn't_ implemented like that right now? How is `equals` implemented then?

Comment: I think if importantVal is unique for all objects then set.remove(new Data(10, anyPlaceholderValue)) will give O(1) complexity. But only if equals method is defined correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a `Map<Integer, Data>` instead of a set.

Comment: Your hashCode and equals method should absolutely follow the same logic?!

Answer (score 2):

## No, object required, hash code does not suffice

> How can I remove an item by its hashCode, without knowing the object itself?

You cannot.

The hash code is only the first step in tracking an object within a `HashSet` or `HashMap`.

Hash codes are not necessarily unique. Two different objects may coincidentally have the same hash code result. Such collisions are expected.

So a hash-based collection is built to secondarily track the colliding objects as a group, and work through them by using the `equals` method. Equality is used to differentiate between objects that happen to produce the same hash code calculation result.

So you cannot retrieve an object from a hash-driven collection using only its hash code calculated value. The original object is needed for the equality test.

And this explains why your `equals` and `hashCode` methods must use mutually consistent logic. And, of course, never override one without overriding the other.

See: [*How does a Java HashMap handle different objects with the same hash code?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6493605/642706).

## `Map`

If you want to track objects for speedy retrieval by a particular property of that class such as a unique identifier, use a `Map` rather than a `Set`. A map tracks key-value pairings.

For example, we want to track each person by their assigned identifier, a UUID.

```
record Person ( UUID id , String name , String phone ) {}
```

So we define a mapping of UUID to `Person`.

```
Map< UUID , Person > map = new HashMap<>() ;
```

Instantiate an object of that class.

```
UUID id = UUID.fromString( "5595d84e-b86b-11eb-8529-0242ac130003" ) ;
Person alice = new Person( id , "Alice" , "555-1234" ) ;
```

Add a `Person` object to the map.

```
map.put( alice.id() , alice ) ;
```

Retrieve.

```
Person x = map.get( UUID.fromString( "5595d84e-b86b-11eb-8529-0242ac130003" ) ) ;
```

Comment: "Ole iron"? A Spanish alloy?

Comment: @tgdavies I’ll have to fire Siri as my copy-editor. Thanks, fixed now.