# Java Memory Model

Tags: java

In a recent interview interviewer asked me to explain Java Memory Model. So I started explaining Heap (New Generation, Old generation etc) Stack.But he said this is in terms if Garbage Collector. I am not interested in this. Worse thing about interview was he did not give me a chance to ask a single question.

Can any one tell me what exactly that guy was looking for?

Comment: not a relevant question here

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question. It's been asked before on SO, so I don't see why this time it is not relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005061/java-memory-model

Comment: "to explain Java Memory Model"? what is the job title, chief scientist?

Comment: "Can anyone tell me what exactly that guy was looking for?"  He can.

Comment: [The Java Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with question. Just wanted to know what could be possible answer.

Comment: @zhong.j.yu The job Title was Senior Software Engg.

Comment: He probably wanted to hear how GC decides which objects should be removed from memory. Why? Maybe to test your knowledge about [memory leaks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6470651/1393766). Who knows?

Comment: @Pshemo I explained him about GC as well like mark and sweep algo, finalize method and all but he keep saying no.

Comment: Well after searching a lot I came to know there are 5 memory regions in JVM
(1) Class Area
(2) Heap
(3) Stack 
(4) PC Register
(5) Native Method Stack

I am going to read them in details.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely he was referring to [the concurrency model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Memory_Model) of how and when changes to memory are visible to other threads. That commonly goes under the name of the "Java Memory Model", as the Wikipedia article illustrates.

It seems a bit silly to base the question on a piece of terminology, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I believe concurrency is just a way to handle variables in  memory.

Comment: "But"? I don't see what contradiction you are trying to point out. :)

Comment: @user1951754 "Java Memory Model" has a very specific meaning which is defined in the Java Language Specification and adresses how a Java program should behave in the presence of several threads.

Comment: @Dolda2000 what exactly I mean to say that concurrency model as you said commonly goes under the name of the Java Memory Model. But I do not think interviewer was looking for this. We all know how concurrency stuff works and it is a new feature in JDK 1.5 and memory model exists since the first release of Java.

Comment: Well, naturally, *a* memory model has always existed, but up until Java 1.5 it was thought to suck, so the introduction of the new memory model was a rather Big Thing. Since "Java Memory Model" is the canonical term for this, I would think that if he was not looking for the heap/GC model, he ought to have been referring to this. You say that "We all know how concurrency stuff works", but I don't think the barrier model and partial ordering of memory operations is all that common knowledge.

Comment: Well after searching a lot I came to know there are 5 memory regions in JVM
(1) Class Area
(2) Heap
(3) Stack 
(4) PC Register
(5) Native Method Stack

I am going to read them in details.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is the stuff they asked. It explains the java memory management.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he wanted you to say that the garbage collector manages the memory occupied by objects and reclaims it back when it's no longer needed.

Comment: The Garbage Collector and the Memory Model are two different topics.

Comment: did you read ALL of his topic?