# Is memory leaks possible in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am a beginner in the java programming language. Recently I have studied the workings of the java garbage collector, **System.gc();** in detail (internally how it uses Copying and Shifting methods to DE-allocate and then reallocate memory). I just want to know whether memory leaks are possible in java or not?

Comment: [Creating a memory leak with java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java?rq=1)

Comment: ok i have checked it, and i got my answer, thanks for your suggestion.