# Does java leak memory when an object is open()-ed but never close()-d?

Tags: java, resource-leak

Just to understand the various ways in which memory leaks can happen in Java. Is it safe to say that the most general way is when a reference to an object is created and never released?

Ex :

```
DBManager db = new DBManager();
db.open();
```

and no call to :

```
db.close();
```

Comment: The most difficult part of the java that you don't know where the leak.

Comment: This is rather a resource leak than a memory leak. There is a long thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java about the topic of Java memory leaks.

Comment: The situation you described is not a memory leak because you still can access `db`.

Comment: when your program terminates so will your database connection. it's sloppy to leave it open, but in a short-lives program it shouldn't cause too much issues. Get into a habit of building some sort of RuntimeManager class that you can call a `shutdown()` method on before exiting your program (and it will take care of closing all your resources, etc).