# Is there a way to lock cursor in java

Tags: java, cursor, game-development

For example Minecraft while playing the cursor is locked/hidden in the middle of the screen but the application can still take in the mouse movements.

[Here is how it looks in minecraft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWx6p.png)

> How to accomplish this in java app?

*Do i need to use openGL or lwjGl or can this be done with 'Vanilla Java'*

Thank you!!

Comment: This may relate to your question: [Java - Freeze Mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724973/java-freeze-mouse)

Comment: You could simply hide the mouse cursor and draw a center cross to get a similar effect. However that would still allow the user to move the mouse outside of the window - unless it is maximized to the desktop.

Comment: @EskandarAbedini Thank you that is a good solution... i will try that out!