# Is my Java code causing memory leaks

Tags: java, heroku, memory-leaks, playframework, out-of-memory

My app is constantly running out of memory. I am using a static instance of most Classes to perform operations that have no state, but I am worried that this is the cause of my memory leaks.

My tech stack is `heroku/playframework 1.2.7/mongodb (compose.io)`

The basic pattern I have is:

```
public class Product{

  public productName;
  public productDesc;
  public productPrice;

  private static final Product INSTANCE = new Product();

  public static Product instance() {
      return INSTANCE;
  }

  // an example (not actual) method is
  public List<Product> listAllProducts(String brand, String category){
       //not the actual DB code
       Db.connect().find(Product.class).listAllItems(brand, category);   
  }

}
```

Which I use like this

```
 List<Product> products = Product.instance().listAllProducts("hugo-boss", "jeans");
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong with this code that will cause memory leaks in a web app with a handful - but not a huge number of concurrent users?

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**
Doing `heroku config:set _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms256m -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops"` didnt' work for now.

I enabled one of the add-ons that gives memory info in the logs, here's what I'm getting:

```
2015-01-09T16:18:58.614435+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=web.3 dyno=heroku.18312286.ad920471-c3dd-4d5d-a55b-28ea79905c14 sample#load_avg_1m=3.65
2015-01-09T16:18:58.614631+00:00 heroku[web.3]: source=web.3 dyno=heroku.18312286.ad920471-c3dd-4d5d-a55b-28ea79905c14 sample#memory_total=439.86MB sample#memory_rss=438.86MB sample#memory_cache=1.00MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=138042pages sample#memory_pgpgout=25438pages
2015-01-09T16:19:10.683077+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.18312286.910cbbef-7613-4daf-a856-230e08618cc7 sample#load_avg_1m=1.90 sample#load_avg_5m=0.86
2015-01-09T16:19:10.683364+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.18312286.910cbbef-7613-4daf-a856-230e08618cc7 sample#memory_total=367.73MB sample#memory_rss=365.02MB sample#memory_cache=2.71MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=141344pages sample#memory_pgpgout=47205pages
```

Comment: If the answer is no, this should be fine, then please feel free to tell me that as well.

Comment: Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java

Comment: Try starting up the JVM console and then run your app: you should be able to see where the memory is going.

Comment: You can tell the JVM to dump the heap when it runs out of memory and load that in a tool to identify what is leaking

Comment: @m-z thanks, I've done that ... if in 5 or so min the memory issues don't start then I think that means it's worked. Will let you know ASAP

Comment: @m-z that doesn't seem to work, I'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

There is no leak here. At least, not in the code you posted. 
But, depending on how large your list is, and how large heap you are running with, you might be running OOM simply because you are trying to create several copies of the "allProducts" list simultaneously.

Perhaps, it is better to cache the list of "all products", and let all clients use that single instance?

Comment: Well usually the products are retrieved based on values such as which company, category etc. -- would that by any chance make a difference?

Comment: No.  That wouldn't lead to a memory leak.