# Is it safe to store an Entry from a Map? Can it cause memory leaks?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm running into this code (adapted with dummy data):

```
public Map<String, Integer> queryDatabase() {
    final Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put("one", 1);
    map.put("two", 2);
    // ...
    return map;
}

public Map.Entry<String, Integer> getEntry(int n) {
    final Map<String, Integer> map = queryDatabase();
    for (final Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(n)) return entry; // dummy check
    }
    return null;
}
```

The `Entry` is then stored into a newly-created object that is saved into a cache for an undefined period:

```
class DataBundle {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry;

    public void doAction() {
    this.entry = Application.getEntry(2);
    }
}
```

While `queryDatabase` is called multiple times in a minute, the local Maps should be discarded at the consequent gc cycle. I have reason to believe though, that `DataBundle` keeping an `Entry` reference prevents the `Map` from being collected at all.

Besides, a `java.util.TreeMap.Entry` holds multiple references to siblings:

```
static final class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    K key;
    V value;
    Entry<K,V> left;
    Entry<K,V> right;
    Entry<K,V> parent;
    // ...
}
```

---

**Q:** Does storing a `Map.Entry` into a member field retain the local `Map` instances into memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract for [Map.Entry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) does not make any commitments in that area so you should not make any assumptions either.

> ... These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the duration of the iteration; ...

For this reason, if you wish to store `Key-Value` pairs derived from a `Map.Entry` then you should take copies.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a benchmarking application and the results clearly demonstrate that the JVM is **not able to collect the local `Map` instances** if an `Entry` reference is kept alive.

This applies only to `TreeMap`s though and the reason might be that a `TreeMap.Entry` holds different references to its siblings.

As @OldCurmudgeon mentions,

> you should not make any assumptions [and] if you wish to store Key-Value pairs derived from a Map.Entry then you should take copies

I believe that at this point, if you don't know what you are doing, whatever `Map` you are working with, holding a `Map.Entry` should be considered **evil** and **anti-pattern**.

Always opt for saving copies of `Map.Entry` or directly store the key and value.

---

**Benchmarking technical data:**

JVM

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

CPU

```
Caption           : Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9
DeviceID          : CPU0
Manufacturer      : GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed     : 4201
Name              : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700K CPU @ 4.20GHz
SocketDesignation : LGA1151
```

RAM

```
Model Name                  MaxCapacity MemoryDevices
----- ----                  ----------- -------------
      Physical Memory Array    67108864             4
```

---

**What will the benchmark do?**

- The main program will (pseudo-)query the database `500` times
- A new instance of `DataBundle` will be created at each iteration an will store a random `Map.Entry` by calling `getEntry(int)`
- `queryDatabase` is going to create a local `TreeMap` of `100_000` items at each call and `getEntry` will simply return one `Map.Entry` from the Map.
- All `DataBundle` instances will be stored into an `ArrayList` cache.
- How `DataBundle` stores the `Map.Entry` will be different among the benchmarks, in order to demonstrate the `gc` abilities to perform its duty.
- Every `100` calls to `queryDatabase` the `cache` will be cleared: this is to see the effect of the `gc` in [visualvm](https://visualvm.github.io/)

---

**Benchmark 1: TreeMap and storing Map.Entry - CRASH**

The `DataBundle` class:

```
class DataBundle {
    Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = null;
    public DataBundle(int i) {
        this.entry = Benchmark_1.getEntry(i);
    }
}
```

The benchmarking application:

```
public class Benchmark_1 {
    static final List<DataBundle> CACHE = new ArrayList<>();
    static final int MAP_SIZE = 100_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            if (i % 100 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Clearing");
                CACHE.clear();
            }
            final DataBundle dataBundle = new DataBundle(new Random().nextInt(MAP_SIZE));
            CACHE.add(dataBundle);
            Thread.sleep(500); // to observe behavior in visualvm
        }
    }

    public static Map<String, Integer> queryDatabase() {
        final Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++) map.put(String.valueOf(i), i);
        return map;
    }
    public static Map.Entry<String, Integer> getEntry(int n) {
        final Map<String, Integer> map = queryDatabase();
        for (final Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
            if (entry.getValue().equals(n)) return entry;
        return null;
    }
}
```

The application can't even reach the first `100` iterations (the cache clearing) and it throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:832)
    at org.payloc.benchmark.Benchmark_1.queryDatabase(Benchmark_1.java:34)
    at org.payloc.benchmark.Benchmark_1.getEntry(Benchmark_1.java:38)
    at org.payloc.benchmark.DataBundle.<init>(Benchmark_1.java:11)
    at org.payloc.benchmark.Benchmark_1.main(Benchmark_1.java:26)
Mar 22, 2018 1:06:41 PM sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop executeAcceptLoop
WARNING: RMI TCP Accept-0: accept loop for 
ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=31158] throws
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getAll(Native Method)
    at java.net.NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(NetworkInterface.java:343)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:86)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message can't create byte arrau at JPLISAgent.c line: 813
```

The `visualvm` graph clearly shows how the memory is retained despite the `gc` performing some activity in the background, ergo: **holding a single `Entry` keeps the entire `Map` in the heap.**

[image: Benchmark_1: Heap Memory]

[image: Benchmark_1: GC Activity]

**Benchmark 2: HashMap and storing Map.Entry - PASS**

Very same program, but instead of a `TreeMap` I'm using a `HashMap`.

The `gc` is able to collect the local `Map` instances despite the stored `Map.Entry` being kept into memory, *(If you tried in fact to print the `cache` result after the benchmark you will see actual values).*

`visualvm` graphs:

[image: Benchmark_2: Heap Memory]
[image: Benchmark_2: GC Activity]

The application does not throw any memory error.

**Benchmark 3: TreeMap and storing only key and value (no Map.Entry) - PASS**

Still using a `TreeMap`, but this time, instead of the `Map.Entry`, I will be storing the key and the value data directly.

```
class DataBundle3 {
    String key;
    Integer value;

    public DataBundle3(int i) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> e = Benchmark_3.getEntry(i);
        this.key = e.getKey();
        this.value = e.getValue();
    }
}
```

Safe approach, as the application reaches the end correctly and the `gc` periodically cleans the maps.

[image: Benchmark_3: Heap Memory]
[image: Benchmark_3: GC Activity]

**Benchmark 4: TreeMap and cache of SoftReference (storing Map.Entry) - PASS**

Not the best solution, but since many caching systems use `java.lang.ref.SoftReference` I'll post a benchmark with it.

So, still using a `TreeMap`, still storing the `Map.Entry` into `DataBundle`, but using a List of `SoftReference<DataBundle>`.

So the cache becomes:

```
static final List<SoftReference<DataBundle>> CACHE = new ArrayList<>();
```

and I save the objects via:

```
CACHE.add(new SoftReference<>(dataBundle));
```

The application completes correctly, and the `gc` is free to collect the maps anytime it needs to.
This happens because `SoftReference` doesn't retain its `referent` (in our case the `Map.Entry`) from being collected.

[image: Benchmark_4: Heap Memory]
[image: Benchmark_4: GC Activity]

---

Hope this will be useful for someone.

Comment: Great analysis. But how can the underlying *HashMap* be GCed when underlying Map.Entry is stored. Don't both `HashMap` and a `TreeMap`'s entrySet an *inner* class. Does it have to do with the extra siblings you mentioned?

Comment: @user7 the inner Entry's are `static` classes: so they do not hold a reference to the parent `class` anyway. I **honestly** am not sure what causes the `TreeMap.Entry` to retain the entire map in memory. So my only guess, by looking at the implementation, is: the references chain created by the `TreeMap.Entry`. It would be better to hear words from someone with more expertize, but this question unfortunately hasn't received much attention...

Comment: The nested class is not *static*. This is the declaration `final class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>`