# Are stack overflow errors considered memory leak errors?

Tags: java

In Java? Yes or no? Simple question, but I can't find a definitive answer anywhere. 
Most explanations of memory leaks I read only concern the heap, as if this cannot happen in the stack.

This is not answered by the "Creating a memory leak with Java" stack overflow question because that article makes no mention of whether stack overflow errors are considered a kind of memory leak.

Comment: No. Simple answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a memory leak with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/creating-a-memory-leak-with-java)

Comment: @MC Emperor I added an explanation of why this question is not answered by that

Comment: No memory is *leaked* at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A memory leak is a scenario that occurs when objects are no longer being used by the application. I think in the case of a recursive call, the objects are required at a later point. So I would not consider a stack overflow error a memory leak.

Comment: Nice way of putting it.

Comment: Thanks, I was considering using this as a simple answer to "how to create a memory leak in Java?" interview question but it looks like I would be dead wrong

Answer (score 7):

"Memory leak", in brief, refers to the scenario that memory is allocated but not released even if it is no longer needed.

A stack overflow itself is NOT causing any unneeded memory to fail to be released.  There is no reason that you can treat a stack overflow as a "memory leak".