# How to properly override close() method from java.io.Closeable to kill an object?

Tags: java

My goal is to understand on how to properly override `close()` method from `java.io.Closeable`.

I actually don't understand why some class like `java.util.Scanner` `close()` method only change the field `closed` to true and then on `next()` method it always do the `ensureOpen()` method before executing other method, essentially it makes me to think that `close()` method is just for the aesthetic aspect instead of to prevent `memory leak`.

I tried to create a test, based on assumption that `close()` method

```
Closeable Closes this stream and releases any system resources associated with it. If the stream is already closed then invoking this method has no effect.
```

My expected result: `printer.println("should not print");` should fail.

My actual result: `printer.println("should not print");` print the result.

Application.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Printer printer = new Printer();
    try (printer) {
      printer.println("hello");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    printer.println("should not print");

  }
}
```

Printer.java

```
public class Printer implements Closeable {
  public void println(String x) {
    System.out.println(x);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    System.out.println(Printer.class + " close");
  }
}
```

EDIT: Following the discussion with @Turing85, I am following the `java.util.Scanner` pattern to use `flag-option`

```
public class Printer implements Closeable {
  private boolean closed = false;

  private void ensureOpen() {
    if (this.closed)
      throw new IllegalStateException("Printer closed");
  }

  public void println(String x) {
    ensureOpen();
    System.out.println(x);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    this.closed = true;
    System.out.println("Printer closed");
  }
}
```

Comment: In `close()`, either call `System.out.close()` to close `System.out` (Attention: this will close `System.out`, itt cannot be reopened, hence for the remainder of the program execution, no output can be written to `System.out`) or set a flag, e.g. `boolean closed` (initialized with `false`) to `true`. If you go for the flag-option, only call `System.out.println(...)` in `println(...)` if `closed` is `false`.

Comment: @Turing85 does `close()` method is to kill `Printer` object OR to just prevent me to access e.g `Printer.println()` in the future after `close()` method, asumming I go with the `flag-option`? I am asumming it is better to do just `printer = null` than `printer.close()` if I wish to release resource, am I right?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "*kill*". An object cannot be "killed". The semantics of `Closeable::close` are described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html#close()). The documentation does say nothing about the behaviour wrt. subsequent calls to `println(...)` or alike. I would not set the `printer` to `null` without further changes since this would lead to a `NullPointerException` on a subsequent `println(...)`-call.

Comment: @Turing85 "kill" an object in this case to release the object from the memory, to make space for other object. Does `printer = null` will release the system resource associated with `printer` or this will cause memory leak because `printer = null` will only remove the reference?

Comment: Java does not work this way. For one, objects are not explicitly destroyed, but garbage-collected by the garbage collector if they are unreachable. For another, `System.out` is still reachable since... it is reachable through `System.out`. I believe you are overthinking things here.

Comment: @Turing85 Well noted. Thank you for the time. I will try to look for proper usage of implementing Closeable to prevent memory leak in the future before writing the question.

Comment: @Turing85 I have a theory of `java.io.Closeable` usage, please kindly check down below in the answer section, what do you think?

Answer (score -1):

After some thought, coupled with dependency injection concept. I came into conclusion that implementation of `java.io.Closeable` is to prevent memory leak. Here's how you are going to use it.

You don't do this.

```
public class Printer {
  private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

Instead, you do this

```
public class Printer {
  private final Scanner scanner;

  public Printer(Scanner scanner) {
    this.scanner = scanner;
  }
}
```

And then you call it with

```
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Printer printer = new Printer(new Scanner(System.in));

    // or maybe like this
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Printer printer = new Printer(scanner);

    // do something
    // e.g call method from the printer object that use scanner method.

    scanner.close();
    printer = null;
    scanner = null;
  }
}
```

I come to conclusion that `If you create an object that have dependency of let's say, a class that will do IO operation`, you use implement `java.io.Closeable`

So this is the simplest implementation of java.io.Closeable that I can think of to prevent memory leak.

Printer.java

```
package Closeable;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Printer implements Closeable {
  private boolean closed = false;

  private Scanner scanner;

  public Printer(Scanner scanner) {
    this.scanner = scanner;
  }

  private void ensureOpen() {
    if (this.closed)
      throw new IllegalStateException("Printer closed");
  }

  public void next() {
    ensureOpen();
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {
    scanner.close();
    this.closed = true;
    System.out.println("Printer closed");
  }
}
```

And you use it like this.

```
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Printer printer = new Printer(new Scanner(System.in));
    try (printer) {
      printer.next();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    printer.next();

  }
}
```

Comment: `Closeable` has nothing to do with memory leaks. In fact, it is [quite hard to create an actual memory leak in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/how-can-i-create-a-memory-leak-in-java). `Closeable` is more about limited resources that should be returned to the OS ([as stated in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Closeable.html)).