Why does a memory leak not appear?
I need Java code to produce a memory leak. I know unclosed resources can be the reason for memory leaks. I know that construction try-with-resources is used to avoid memory leaks. But now I need to create memory leaks for demonstration profiling tools.
I wrote simple code.
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class UnclosedResources {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        while (true) {
            new FileInputStream(Arrays.stream(new File(".").listFiles()).iterator().next());
        }
    }
}

I have monitored resources. The memory leak doesn’t appear.
no leaks
Why does this code work without memory leaks?
What should I do to produce memory leaks?

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470651/how-can-i-create-a-memory-leak-in-java

try-with-resources is used to call close on the object at a well-defined time. If you don't use it, the close will happen when the object is eventually garbage collected. Which in this case happens immediately (insert explanation of generations). With some changes, similar code could cause the jvm to run out of file descriptors. Not quite out of memory though.

"I know unclosed resources can be the reason for memory leaks." - Actually that isn't true.  It causes a resource leak because a potentially scarce external resource won't be released (back to the operating system) until the GC runs.  It is not a memory leak per se because the Java memory associated with the resource will be released by the GC when it eventually runs.

Hence ... when you run that code in a framework that looks for memory leaks, it shouldn't find one.  If you wanted to create a memory leak you would need to store the FileInputStream objects in (say) a List that never becomes unreachable.  However, there is a good chance that the code would fail with a IOException before the memory leak could be detected.  It would probably consume all of the JVM processes file descriptor slots, and a open syscall would fail.

So ... basically ... you need to understand the difference between a resource leak and a memory leak, and work out which of the two you are actually trying to cause to happen.

An example for a memory leak would be List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>(); for(long l = 1; list.isEmpty(); l++) { list.add(l); list = list.subList(0, 0); }
